# How do I migrate an SVN repository with history to a new Git repository?

Tags: svn, git, version-control, git-svn

I read the Git manual, FAQ, Git - SVN crash course, etc. and they all explain this and that, but nowhere can you find a simple instruction like:

SVN repository in: `svn://myserver/path/to/svn/repos`

Git repository in: `git://myserver/path/to/git/repos`

```
git-do-the-magic-svn-import-with-history \
svn://myserver/path/to/svn/repos \
git://myserver/path/to/git/repos
```

I don't expect it to be that simple, and I don't expect it to be a single command. But I do expect it not to try to explain anything - just to say what steps to take given this example.

Comment: It is getting easier, I just completed it myself and documented my findings with the help of SO http://jmoses.co/2014/03/21/moving-from-svn-to-git.html

Comment: Use Casey's answer below, but before you run the "svn clone ..." command, see how to add the extra "Visual SVN Server" line to your user.txt file... here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971208/svn2git-failing-saying-author-visualsvn-server-not-defined-in-authors-txt-fil

Comment: Also, if you have the "make email private option checked in your GitHub profile, use this as your email address in users.txt to match.   yourgituser@users.noreply.github.com, so your real email address doesn't show up on commits.

Comment: Related: [Migrating from SVN to Git, preserving branches and tags](https://web.archive.org/web/20190913135634/http://www.sailmaker.co.uk/blog/2013/05/05/migrating-from-svn-to-git-preserving-branches-and-tags-3/)

Comment: To migrate from Google Code, read: [How to recover a Google Code SVN Project and migrate to Github](https://dominikdorn.com/2016/05/how-to-recover-a-google-code-svn-project-and-migrate-to-github/)

Answer (score 552, accepted):

Magic:

```
$ git svn clone http://svn/repo/here/trunk
```

Git and SVN operate very differently.  You need to learn Git, and if you want to track changes from SVN upstream, you need to learn `git-svn`.  The `git-svn` [main page has a good examples section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn):

```
$ git svn --help
```

Comment: Use CPAN to install the Error module, I think. You can use git-svn for a one-time migration.

Comment: @Milan: I get this error when the subversion perl bindings are not installed.

Comment: The answer from @Casey answers the original question much better.

Comment: Will this keep the branches and everything? or just clone the trunk?

Comment: @Eildosa: This will just clone the trunk. See Casey's answer for an alternative.

Comment: It does not preserve commit date times. Is there any workaround? I have found some releated topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795070/is-there-a-way-in-git-to-obtain-a-push-date-for-a-given-commit. I don't know if it is possible to use it from git svn clone.

Comment: @DougWilson but I can't see any Casey's answer here. Is it the answer below with 13 authors that begins with "Create a users file"?

Comment: For anyone else who's wondering which is "Casey's answer" which is referenced in lots of comments around here, it's [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3972103/122687) (Casey changed his nick to cmcginty).

Comment: This basically works but there is more to it. For example migrating / matching user names or working on both repos at the same time during transition period. Here are some more details I found: https://itcodehub.blogspot.com/2015/08/how-to-migrate-svn-repository-to-git.html

Answer (score 1663):

Create a users file (i.e. `users.txt`) for mapping SVN users to Git:

```
user1 = First Last Name <email@address.com>
user2 = First Last Name <email@address.com>
...
```

You can use this one-liner to build a template from your existing SVN repository:

```
svn log -q | awk -F '|' '/^r/ {gsub(/ /, "", $2); sub(" $", "", $2); print $2" = "$2" <"$2">"}' | sort -u > users.txt
```

SVN will stop if it finds a missing SVN user, not in the file. But after that, you can update the file and pick up where you left off.

Now pull the SVN data from the repository:

```
git svn clone --stdlayout --no-metadata --authors-file=users.txt svn://hostname/path dest_dir-tmp
```

This command will create a new Git repository in `dest_dir-tmp` and start pulling the SVN repository. Note that the "--stdlayout" flag implies you have the common "trunk/, branches/, tags/" SVN layout. If your layout differs, become familiar with `--tags`, `--branches`, `--trunk` options (in general `git svn help`).

All common protocols are allowed: `svn://`, `http://`, `https://`. The URL should target the base repository, something like http://svn.mycompany.com/myrepo/repository. The URL string must **not** include `/trunk`, `/tag` or `/branches`.

Note that after executing this command it very often looks like the operation is "hanging/frozen", and it's quite normal that it can be stuck for a long time after initializing the new repository. Eventually, you will then see log messages which indicate that it's migrating.

Also note that if you omit the `--no-metadata` flag, Git will append information about the corresponding SVN revision to the commit message (i.e. `git-svn-id: svn://svn.mycompany.com/myrepo/<branchname/trunk>@<RevisionNumber> <Repository UUID>`)

If a user name is not found, update your `users.txt` file then:

```
cd dest_dir-tmp
git svn fetch
```

You might have to repeat that last command several times, if you have a large project until all of the Subversion commits have been fetched:

```
git svn fetch
```

When completed, Git will checkout the SVN `trunk` into a new branch. Any other branches are set up as remotes. You can view the other SVN branches with:

```
git branch -r
```

If you want to keep other remote branches in your repository, you want to create a local branch for each one manually.  (Skip trunk/master.)  If you don't do this, the branches won't get cloned in the final step.

```
git checkout -b local_branch remote_branch
# It's OK if local_branch and remote_branch are the same names
```

Tags are imported as branches. You have to create a local branch, make a tag and delete the branch to have them as tags in Git. To do it with tag "v1":

```
git checkout -b tag_v1 remotes/tags/v1
git checkout master
git tag v1 tag_v1
git branch -D tag_v1
```

Clone your GIT-SVN repository into a clean Git repository:

```
git clone dest_dir-tmp dest_dir
rm -rf dest_dir-tmp
cd dest_dir
```

The local branches that you created earlier from remote branches will only have been copied as remote branches into the newly cloned repository. (Skip trunk/master.) For each branch you want to keep:

```
git checkout -b local_branch origin/remote_branch
```

Finally, remove the remote from your clean Git repository that points to the now-deleted temporary repository:

```
git remote rm origin
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I did all the basic import steps and then noticed that all my branches were remotes and wasn't sure what to do to resolve it.

Comment: This blog post by Eelke is a great cross-reference for the answer above. http://blokspeed.net/blog/2010/09/converting-from-subversion-to-git/

Comment: This is 99% awesome, following these steps, I got everything in order except branches: after the final step, they were remote only (and as such disappeared when I did the command: git remote rm origin)

Comment: I too have been struggeling with the branches part. After migrating a SVN repo with five branches and following this guide only one branch were checked out. I think there is missing a "git pull" command somewhere??? Also: If i do the step that removes the remote branches, my local branches are also removed. - So i don't see the point in removing the remote branches. So I skipped the last step where you cut out the remote and now (I think) it works as supposed to.

Comment: You could add this step to find all users who committed to the repo. http://superuser.com/questions/130326/list-of-all-users-who-committed-to-a-svn-repository

Comment: I find that `git svn clone` bombs when using the ``--no-metadata`` flag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398415/git-svn-clone-fails-unexpectedly

Comment: Try to look also to http://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git It seems a very good step-by-step procedure

Comment: I just used this procedure and it worked pretty well. My observations are: 1) the process for converting "tag branches" to tags still leaves the branches (albeit unlabelled). If you created the tag in SVN without modifying the content, then you can actually tag the preceding commit and delete the "tag-branch" for cleaner history. 2) no mention is made of migrating the svn:ignore attributes. This is covered elsewhere on The Internet. See also 'git svn show-ignore'. 3) the final clone didn't benefit me. Indeed, I ended up with remote refs to the original dir, which was odd.

Comment: GitHub has a very convenient step-by-step: https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git#readme

Comment: I had to add an '(no author)' line in my users.txt file as mentioned here: http://blokspeed.net/blog/2010/09/converting-from-subversion-to-git/  I also got `Use of uninitialized value in substitution` and had to follow this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/msysgit/7MQVwRO-2N4

Comment: And I had to remove spaces near the `=` character from `users.txt`  because `somebody = Somebody <mail@mail.com>` didn't work (import aborted after first commit, leaving an empty repository) but `somebody=Somebody <mail@mail.com>` worked fine.

Comment: Ah yes, the [git documentation link](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git) provided in [kpd's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4974152/210945) has a nice way to get the SVN users.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer. I needed to extract a project out of a non-stdlayout repo. The project lived in a repo subfolder and had it's own trunk/branches/tags sub-structure. I had to use the base repo path and `--trunk=Path/To/MyProject/trunk` option. I didn't specify any branch or tag option as these were not required. I had some strange behaviour where `git svn` kept stopping early and the final trunk was not the latest svn commit. Finally figured out that I had to `cd dest_dir-temp` and `git svn fetch` multiple times until got the latest revision!

Comment: If the svn repository changes since you did the initial `git svn clone` (or after `git svn fetch` if there were interrupts), the `master` branch diverts from the remote `trunk` when svn fetching again. To fix this before you clone your temp repo in the clean repo use `git checkout master`  and `git reset --hard trunk`. Now `master` points to latest revision from trunk again.

Comment: I would checkout svn repo first and do this to populate users.txt  `svn log -q | awk -F '|' '/^r/ {sub("^ ", "", $2); sub(" $", "", $2); print $2" = "$2" <"$2">"}' | sort -u > users.txt`

Comment: Should probably update this with: `git svn show-ignore > .gitignore`

Comment: For those under Windows, I created a PowerShell script based on this method:
https://gist.github.com/Gimly/90df046dc38181bb18de

Comment: For create tag in one command
`git checkout -b tagg origin/tags/1.0 ; git checkout master;git tag v1.0 tagg;git branch -D tagg;`
Only change tagname 1.0.

Comment: **Warning** for large repos with a lot of history, this is **slow and tedius**.  I gave up trying to migrate all the old branches and simply migrated trunk.

Comment: @Jess: Just as a note, but the reason it's so slow is that Git has to turn each Subversion check-in into a local commit as it builds up the repo. A large repo can take several hours (even overnight), so I'd recommend planning ahead

Comment: I had some commit messages which included the word "author".  using `grep "<author>" ` instead of just `grep "author" ` avoided adding extra lines to the template file.  Also, since our usernames are of the form firstname.lastname I can actually use

` svn log --xml | grep "<author>" | sort -u | perl -pe 's/.*>(.*?)<.*/$1 = /' | sed -e 's/\(.*\)\.\(.*\) \= /\1.\2 = \u\1 \u\2 <\1.\2@example.com>/'`

to generate the whole file!  haven't got as far as the actual import yet since our SVN structure is not totally standard but looks good.

Comment: Or, even shorter

`svn log --xml | sed -n 's/^<author>\(.*\)\.\(.*\)<\/author>/\1.\2 = \u\1 \u\2 <\1.\2@example.com>/p' | sort -u`

Surprisingly this runs if anything very slightly faster than even the original version with grep and perl.

Comment: you'll need to create a bare git repository and to import the cloned git files there, if you're hosting your git repository by your own

Comment: May I use the standard layout even though I don't have branch and tag subfolders, but only trunk?

Comment: To retrieve the SVN repository, @zoul 's post below was easier to follow because of git svn init and git svn fetch commands instead of git svn clone.  Once I had the repository, this post was very helpful to get it cleaned up with git clone.

Comment: I don't know how many times it's been copied, but to preserve vestiges I have to note this answer looks almost a verbatim copy of: https://git.help.collab.net/hc/en-us/community/posts/238452907-Migration-from-Subversion-to-GIT

Comment: What would you do with the old svn repo once you move to git? Shut it down completely? Is there any reason to keep it available?

Comment: Tip: if `--authors-file` doesn't work in your case (for example because a svn username ends with a space) then use the `--authors-prog` option instead which allows supplying a script doing the mapping from svn user to git user.

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli I was unable to confirm your observation with git-svn 2.15. In fact, my `users.txt` had even more than one space in front and behind the equal sign to align them all by the same text column and it worked.

Comment: I too got the `Use of uninitialized value in substitution` error. I'm on Linux but I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4434188/2903608) on SO useful. I.e. delete everything under the [svn-remote "svn"] section.

Comment: If that helps.. I created the following powershell script to grab the authors:

Comment: Had problems with a large repository and losing VPN connection every few hours. Even with using git svn fetch it started again at the beginning afterwards. When you do git svn fetch -r1:1000 it only gets the first 1000 revisions and one can continue later with r1000:2000 etc. like explained at https://heathpaddock.com/2017/08/04/migrating-a-large-subversion-repo-to-git-in-small-chunks/

Comment: In case it is of any help to newcomers, there is an official guide to migrate other VCS' to Git in the [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git)

Answer (score 206):

[Cleanly Migrate Your Subversion Repository To a Git Repository](https://web.archive.org/web/20160314221641/https://jonmaddox.com/2008/03/05/cleanly-migrate-your-subversion-repository-to-a-git-repository/). First you have to create a file that maps your Subversion commit author names to Git commiters, say `~/authors.txt`:

```
jmaddox = Jon Maddox <jon@gmail.com>
bigpappa = Brian Biggs <bigpappa@gmail.com>
```

Then you can download the Subversion data into a Git repository:

```
mkdir repo && cd repo
git svn init http://subversion/repo --no-metadata
git config svn.authorsfile ~/authors.txt
git svn fetch
```

If you’re on a Mac, you can get `git-svn` from MacPorts by installing `git-core +svn`.

If your subversion repository is on the same machine as your desired git repository,
then you can use this syntax for the init step, otherwise all the same:

```
git svn init file:///home/user/repoName --no-metadata
```

Comment: As I commented on the other answer, I had to remove the spaces around `=` in `users.txt` because the import was aborting and I was getting an empty repository.

Comment: Ah! Simple and effective explanation. In my case `file:///` refused to work, just I used `svnserve.exe --daemon` and then used `svn://localhost/home/user/repo` instead.

Comment: On my Mac running Mountain Lion, git svn wouldn't work until I went into Xcode and installed the Command Line Tools found in the Downloads tab of the Preferences pane.  Alternatively, I could have installed just the Command Line Tools for OS X Mountain Lion found on Apple's Developer site.

Comment: For my case I had to convert the file `authors.txt` to `utf-8 without BOM`.

Comment: This worked great for me! Once I had the local repository, I used cmcginty's post starting at "Clone your GIT-SVN repository into a clean Git repository:"  I think the main reason I liked @zoul 's answer was is use of `git svn init`, `git svn config` then finally `git svn fetch` as it was easier to do it this way, I had to fetch several times to get it right.  cmcginty's single-line  `git svn clone`, which does all three, was too muddled for me.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked great for me. However, it does not only migrate the repository, but it also creates the workspace (extracts the repository files to the disk). Any way to avoid this and only keep the `.git` folder?

Answer (score 74):

I used the [svn2git script](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git) and works like a charm.

Comment: Q: does this fix spaces in tag and branch names (allowed in svn and not allowed in git)?

Comment: This guide to use it is helpful: http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/08/migrating-from-subversion-to-git-with.html

Comment: This failed for me with a problem:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/7MQVwRO-2N4  - see also: https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git/issues/50  The solution was here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009738/what-does-this-svn2git-error-mean/4434188#4434188

Comment: It's preferable to explain answers otherwise we produce script kiddies.

Comment: What about if your branches are all in the root of SVN and you have no trunk or tags?

Comment: It seems the repo is unactive now. It has 145 open issues and 30 open pr on the repository.

Answer (score 62):

I suggest getting comfortable with Git before trying to use git-svn constantly, i.e. keeping SVN as the centralized repo and using Git locally.

However, for a simple migration with all the history, here are the few simple steps:

Initialize the local repo:

```
mkdir project
cd project
git svn init http://svn.url
```

Mark how far back you want to start importing revisions:

```
git svn fetch -r42
```

(or just "git svn fetch" for all revs)

Actually, fetch everything since then:

```
git svn rebase
```

You can check the result of the import with Gitk. I'm not sure if this works on Windows, it works on OSX and Linux:

```
gitk
```

When you've got your SVN repo cloned locally, you may want to push it to a centralized Git repo for easier collaboration.

First create your empty remote repo (maybe on [GitHub](http://github.com)?):

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/project-name.git
```

Then, optionally sync your main branch so the pull operation will automatically merge the remote master with your local master when both contain new stuff:

```
git config branch.master.remote origin
git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
```

After that, you may be interested in trying out my very own `git_remote_branch` tool, which helps to deal with remote branches:

First explanatory post: "[Git remote branches](http://programblings.com/2008/06/23/git-remote-branches/)"

Follow-up for the most recent version: "[Time to git collaborating with git_remote_branch](http://programblings.com/2008/08/06/time-to-git-collaborating-with-git_remote_branch/)"

Comment: Extremely helpful, this worked perfectly.  I would add that there is one final step to take if you are synching to a remote repository.  After the git config steps, I needed to `git push origin master`

Answer (score 33):

There is a new solution for smooth migration from Subversion to Git (or for using both simultaneously): [SubGit](http://subgit.com/).

I'm working on this project myself. We use SubGit in our repositories - some of my teammates use Git and some Subversion and so far it works very well.

To migrate from Subversion to Git with SubGit you need to run:

```
$ subgit install svn_repos
...
TRANSLATION SUCCESSFUL
```

After that you'll get Git repository in svn_repos/.git and may clone it, or just continue to use Subversion and this new Git repository together: SubGit will make sure that both are always kept in sync.

In case your Subversion repository contains multiple projects, then multiple Git repositories will be created in svn_repos/git directory. To customize translation before running it do the following:

```
$ subgit configure svn_repos
$ edit svn_repos/conf/subgit.conf (change mapping, add authors mapping, etc)
$ subgit install svn_repos
```

With [SubGit](http://subgit.com/) you may migrate to pure Git (not git-svn) and start using it while still keeping Subversion as long as you need it (for your already configured build tools, for instance).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that a one-time import (using the `subgit import` command) doesn't even seem to require a license. Accurate translation of the `svn:ignore` property to `.gitignore` files is included, too.

Comment: SubGit would not recognize my private key, nor any flags that I set in the command line. Documentation is very poor. This is not a viable alternative for `git svn`.

Comment: error: 'svn_repos' is not a valid configured location; SubGit configuration file is missing.

Answer (score 20):

See the official [git-svn manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn).  In particular, look under "Basic Examples":

> Tracking and contributing to an entire Subversion-managed project (complete
>       with a trunk, tags and branches):

```
# Clone a repo (like git clone):
    git svn clone http://svn.foo.org/project -T trunk -b branches -t tags
```

Comment: Your clone command worked, those above gave me nothing but empty git repos.  The only difference seems to be the explicit '-T trunk'.

Answer (score 15):

## [SubGit](http://www.subgit.com/) (vs Blue Screen of Death)

```
subgit import --svn-url url://svn.serv/Bla/Bla  directory/path/Local.git.Repo
```

It's all.

+ To update from SVN, a Git repository is created by the first command.

```
subgit import  directory/path/Local.git.Repo
```

---

I used a way to migrate to Git instantly for a huge repository. 
Of course, you need some preparation. 
But you may don't stop the development process, at all.

Here is my way.

My solution looks like:

- **Migrate SVN to a Git repository**
- **Update the Git repository just before team's switching to**.

Migration takes a lot of time for a big SVN repository. 
But updating of the completed migration just seconds.

Of course, I'm using [SubGit](http://www.subgit.com/remote-book.html#7), mama.
git-svn makes me [Blue Screen of Death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death). Just constantly.
And git-svn is boring me with Git's "[filename too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123415/git-pull-aborted-with-error-filename-too-long)" fatal error.

**STEPS**

**1.** [Download SubGit](http://www.subgit.com/download.html)

**2.** Prepare migrate and update commands.

Let's say we do it for Windows (it's trivial to port to Linux). 
In a SubGit's installation **bin** directory (subgit-2.X.X\bin), create two .bat files.

Content of a file/command for the migration:

```
start    subgit import --svn-url url://svn.serv/Bla/Bla  directory/path/Local.git.Repo
```

The "start" command is optional here (Windows). It'll allow to see errors on start and left a shell opened after completion of the SubGit.

You may add here [additional parameters similar to git-svn](http://www.subgit.com/remote-book.html#7).
I'm using only **--default-domain myCompanyDomain.com** to fix the domain of the email address of SVN authors. 
I have the standard SVN repository's structure (trunk/branches/tags) and we didn't have troubles with "authors mapping". So I'm doing nothing anymore.

*(If you want to migrate tags like branches or your SVN have multiple branches/tags folders you may consider using the more verbose SubGit [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251394/subgit-import-and-multiple-branches-directories))*

**Tip 1**: Use --minimal-revision YourSvnRevNumber to see fast how things boil out (some kind of a debugging).
Especially useful is to see resolved author names or emails. 
Or to limit the migration history depth.

**Tip 2**: Migration may be interrupted (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) and restored by running of the next updating command/file. 
I don't advise doing this for big repositories. I have received "Out of memory Java+Windows exception".

**Tip 3**: Better to create a copy of your result bare repository.

Content of a file/command for updating:

```
start    subgit import  directory/path/Local.git.Repo
```

You may run it any amount of time when you want to obtain the last team's commits to your Git repository.

**Warning!** Don't touch your bare repository (creation of branches for example). 
You'll take the next fatal error:

> Unrecoverable error: are out of sync and cannot be synced ... Translating Subversion revisions to Git commits...

**3.** Run the first command/file. It'll take a loooong time for a big repository. 30 hours for my humble repository.

It's all. 
You may update your Git repository from SVN at any time any amount of times by running the second file/command. And before switching your development team to Git. 
It'll take just seconds.

---

---

There's one more useful task.

**Push your local Git repository to a remote Git repository**

Is it your case? Let's proceed.

1. Configure your remotes

Run:

```
$ git remote add origin url://your/repo.git
```

2. Prepare to initial send of your huge local Git repository to a remote repository

By default your Git can't send big chunks.
[fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18696820/390940)

Let's run for it:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 1073741824
```

524288000 - 500 MB
1073741824 - 1 GB, etc.

Fix your local [certificate troubles](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&espv=2&q=windows+git+unable+to+get+local+issuer+certificate&oq=windows+git+unable+to+get+local+issuer+certificate&gs_l=serp.3...53528.55201.0.55497.12.9.0.0.0.1.398.398.3-1.1.0.msedr...0...1c.1.61.serp..12.0.0.rqc3smB1Tyo). If your git-server uses a broken certificate.

**I have disabled [certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8755199/390940).**

Also your Git server may have a [request amount limitations needing to be corrected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456025/rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-404).

3. [Push all migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865302/push-local-git-repo-to-new-remote-including-all-branches-and-tags) to the team's remote Git repository.

Run with a local Git:

```
git push origin --mirror
```

(*git push origin '*:*'* for old Git versions)

If you get the following: **error: cannot spawn git: No such file or directory**... For me the full recreation of my repository solves this error (30 hours). You can try the next commands

```
git push origin --all
git push origin --tags
```

Or try to [reinstall Git](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/msysgit/6bFAPUQDQLI/d_ko7gWViC8J) (**useless for me**).
Or you may create branches from all you tags and push them. Or, or, or...

Answer (score 14):

Pro Git 8.2 explains it:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git

Comment: The Pro Git explanation includes migrating the tags and branches.  It uses a local mv rather than svn commands. clever.

Answer (score 13):

## [reposurgeon](http://www.catb.org/esr/reposurgeon/)

For complicated cases, reposurgeon by [Eric S. Raymond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond) is the tool of choice. In addition to SVN, it supports many other version control systems via the `fast-export` format, and also [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System). The author reports successful conversions of ancient repositories such as [Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) and [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD).

The tool apparently [aims at near perfect conversion](http://www.catb.org/~esr/reposurgeon/features.html) (such as converting SVN's `svn:ignore` properties to `.gitignore` files) even for difficult repository layouts with a long history. For many cases, other tools might be easier to use.

Before delving into the documentation of the `reposurgeon` command line, be sure to read the excellent [DVCS migration guide](http://www.catb.org/esr/dvcs-migration-guide.html) which goes over the conversion process step by step.

Answer (score 8):

This guide on atlassian's website is one of the best I have found:

https://www.atlassian.com/git/migration

This tool - https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/svn-migration-scripts - is also really useful for generating your authors.txt among other things.

Comment: This page is wonderful, and is IMHO the best answer!  It does most of the grunt work for you.

Answer (score 8):

You have to Install

```
git
git-svn
```

Copied from this link http://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git.

**1. Retrieve a list of all Subversion committers**

Subversion simply lists the username for each commit. Git’s commits have much richer data, but at its simplest, the commit author needs to have a name and email listed. By default the git-svn tool will just list the SVN username in both the author and email fields. But with a little bit of work, you can create a list of all SVN users and what their corresponding Git name and emails are. This list can be used by git-svn to transform plain svn usernames into proper Git committers.

From the root of your local Subversion checkout, run this command:

```
svn log -q | awk -F '|' '/^r/ {sub("^ ", "", $2); sub(" $", "", $2); print $2" = "$2" <"$2">"}' | sort -u > authors-transform.txt
```

That will grab all the log messages, pluck out the usernames, eliminate any duplicate usernames, sort the usernames and place them into a “authors-transform.txt” file. Now edit each line in the file. For example, convert:

```
jwilkins = jwilkins <jwilkins>
```

into this:

```
jwilkins = John Albin Wilkins <johnalbin@example.com>
```

**2. Clone the Subversion repository using git-svn**

```
git svn clone [SVN repo URL] --no-metadata -A authors-transform.txt --stdlayout ~/temp
```

This will do the standard git-svn transformation (using the authors-transform.txt file you created in step 1) and place the git repository in the “~/temp” folder inside your home directory.

**3. Convert svn:ignore properties to .gitignore**

If your svn repo was using svn:ignore properties, you can easily convert this to a .gitignore file using:

```
cd ~/temp
git svn show-ignore > .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m 'Convert svn:ignore properties to .gitignore.'
```

**4. Push repository to a bare git repository**

First, create a bare repository and make its default branch match svn’s “trunk” branch name.

```
git init --bare ~/new-bare.git
cd ~/new-bare.git
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/trunk
```

Then push the temp repository to the new bare repository.

```
cd ~/temp
git remote add bare ~/new-bare.git
git config remote.bare.push 'refs/remotes/*:refs/heads/*'
git push bare
```

You can now safely delete the ~/temp repository.

**5. Rename “trunk” branch to “master”**

Your main development branch will be named “trunk” which matches the name it was in Subversion. You’ll want to rename it to Git’s standard “master” branch using:

```
cd ~/new-bare.git
git branch -m trunk master
```

**6. Clean up branches and tags**

git-svn makes all of Subversions tags into very-short branches in Git of the form “tags/name”. You’ll want to convert all those branches into actual Git tags using:

```
cd ~/new-bare.git
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/tags |
cut -d / -f 4 |
while read ref
do
  git tag "$ref" "refs/heads/tags/$ref";
  git branch -D "tags/$ref";
done
```

This step will take a bit of typing. :-) But, don’t worry; your unix shell will provide a > secondary prompt for the extra-long command that starts with git for-each-ref.

Answer (score 7):

GitHub now has a feature to [import from an SVN repository](http://github.com/blog/156-subversion-importing). I never tried it, though.

Comment: GitHub's [current recommendation](https://help.github.com/articles/importing-from-subversion) is to use the `svn2git` program suggested in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4860157/470844).

Comment: Imported two quite big projects just now flawlessly. All SVN branches got imported (just remember NOT using \trunk part in repo path). One thing I don't know yet is that whether Github would track new commits.

Answer (score 7):

A somewhat extended answer using just git, SVN, and bash. It includes steps for SVN repositories that do not use the conventional layout with a trunk/branches/tags directory layout (SVN does absolutely nothing to enforce this kind of layout).

First use this bash script to scan your SVN repo for the different people who contributed and to generate a template for a mapping file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
authors=$(svn log -q | grep -e '^r' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|" } ; { print $2 }' | sort | uniq)
for author in ${authors}; do
  echo "${author} = NAME <USER@DOMAIN>";
done
```

Use this to create an `authors` file where you map svn usernames to usernames and email as set by your developers using [`git config`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) properties `user.name` and `user.email` (note that for a service like GitHub only having a matching email is enough).

Then have [`git svn`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) clone the svn repository to a git repository, telling it about the mapping:

`git svn clone --authors-file=authors --stdlayout svn://example.org/Folder/projectroot`

This can take incredibly long, since git svn will individually check out every revision for every tag or branch that exists. (note that tags in SVN are just really branches, so they end up as such in Git). You can speed this up by removing old tags and branches in SVN you don't need.

Running this on a server in the same network or on the same server can also really speed this up. Also, if for some reason this process gets interrupted  you *can* resume it using

`git svn rebase --continue`

In a lot of cases you're done here. But if your SVN repo has an unconventional layout where you simply have a directory in SVN you want to put in a git branch you can do some extra steps.

The simplest is to just make a new SVN repo on your server that does follow convention and use `svn copy` to put your directory in trunk or a branch. This might be the only way if your directory is all the way at the root of the repo, when I last tried this `git svn` simply refused to do a checkout.

You can also do this using git. For `git svn clone` simply use the directory you want to to put in a git branch.

After run

```
git branch --set-upstream master git-svn
git svn rebase
```

Note that this required Git 1.7 or higher.

Comment: I would propose to combine this info with this link: http://www.sailmaker.co.uk/blog/2013/05/05/migrating-from-svn-to-git-preserving-branches-and-tags-3/

Answer (score 7):

I've posted an step by step guide ([here](http://blog.10pines.com/2016/02/24/svn-to-git/)) to convert svn in to git including converting svn tags in to git tags and svn branches in to git branches.

Short version:

1) clone svn from an specific revision number. (the revision number must be the oldest you want to migrate)

```
git svn clone --username=yourSvnUsername -T trunk_subdir -t tags_subdir -b branches_subdir -r aRevisionNumber svn_url gitreponame
```

2) fetch svn data. This step it's the one it takes most time.

```
cd gitreponame
git svn fetch
```

repeat git svn fetch until finishes without error

3) get master branch updated

```
git svn rebase
```

4) Create local branches from svn branches by copying references

```
cp .git/refs/remotes/origin/* .git/refs/heads/
```

5) convert svn tags into git tags

```
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin/tags | sed 's#^.*\([[:xdigit:]]\{40\}\).*refs/remotes/origin/tags/\(.*\)$#\2 \1#g' | while read p; do git tag -m "tag from svn" $p; done
```

6) Put a repository at a better place like github

```
git remotes add newrepo git@github.com:aUser/aProjectName.git
git push newrepo refs/heads/*
git push --tags newrepo
```

If you want more details, read my [post](http://blog.10pines.com/2016/02/24/svn-to-git/) or ask me.

Answer (score 6):

We can use `git svn clone` commands as below.

- `svn log -q <SVN_URL> | awk -F '|' '/^r/ {sub("^ ", "", $2); sub(" $", "", $2); print $2" = "$2" <"$2">"}' | sort -u > authors.txt`

Above command will create authors file from SVN commits.

- `svn log --stop-on-copy <SVN_URL>`

Above command will give you first revision number when your SVN project got created.

- `git svn clone -r<SVN_REV_NO>:HEAD --no-minimize-url --stdlayout --no-metadata --authors-file authors.txt <SVN_URL>`

Above command will create the Git repository in local.

Problem is that it won't convert branches and tags to push. You will have to do them manually. For example below for branches:

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/pankaj0323/JDProjects.git
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/MyDevBranch
  remotes/origin/tags/MyDevBranch-1.0
  remotes/origin/trunk
$$ git checkout -b MyDevBranch origin/MyDevBranch
Branch MyDevBranch set up to track remote branch MyDevBranch from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'MyDevBranch'
$ git branch -a
* MyDevBranch
  master
  remotes/origin/MyDevBranch
  remotes/origin/tags/MyDevBranch-1.0
  remotes/origin/trunk
$
```

For tags:

```
$git checkout origin/tags/MyDevBranch-1.0
Note: checking out 'origin/tags/MyDevBranch-1.0'.
You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at 3041d81... Creating a tag
$ git branch -a
* (detached from origin/tags/MyDevBranch-1.0)
  MyDevBranch
  master
  remotes/origin/MyDevBranch
  remotes/origin/tags/MyDevBranch-1.0
  remotes/origin/trunk
$ git tag -a MyDevBranch-1.0 -m "creating tag"
$git tag
MyDevBranch-1.0
$
```

Now push master, branches and tags to remote git repository.

```
$ git push origin master MyDevBranch MyDevBranch-1.0
Counting objects: 14, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 2.28 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 14 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/pankaj0323/JDProjects.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
 * [new branch]      MyDevBranch -> MyDevBranch
 * [new tag]         MyDevBranch-1.0 -> MyDevBranch-1.0
$
```

## **svn2git utility**

[svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git) utility removes manual efforts with branches and tags.

Install it using command `sudo gem install svn2git`. After that run below command.

- `$ svn2git <SVN_URL> --authors authors.txt --revision <SVN_REV_NO>`

Now you can list the branches, tags and push them easily.

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/pankaj0323/JDProjects.git
$ git branch -a
  MyDevBranch
* master
  remotes/svn/MyDevBranch
  remotes/svn/trunk
$ git tag
  MyDevBranch-1.0
$ git push origin master MyDevBranch MyDevBranch-1.0
```

Imagine you have 20 branches and tags, obviously svn2git will save you a lot of time and that's why I like it better than native commands. It's a nice wrapper around native `git svn clone` command.

For a complete example, refer my [blog entry](http://www.journaldev.com/10618/svn-to-git-migration-complete-tutorial).

Answer (score 5):

TortoiseGit does this. see this blog post: http://jimmykeen.net/articles/03-nov-2012/how-migrate-from-svn-to-git-windows-using-tortoise-clients

Yeah, I know answering with links isn't splendid but it's a solution, eh?

Comment: Try the wayback machine at archive.org

Answer (score 5):

For **GitLab** users I've put up a gist on how I migrated from SVN here:

https://gist.github.com/leftclickben/322b7a3042cbe97ed2af

## Steps to migrate from SVN to GitLab

### Setup

- SVN is hosted at `svn.domain.com.au`.
- SVN is accessible via `http` (other protocols should work).
- GitLab is hosted at `git.domain.com.au` and:

  - A group is created with the namespace `dev-team`.
  - At least one user account is created, added to the group, and has an SSH key for the account being used for the migration (test using `ssh git@git.domain.com.au`).
  - The project `favourite-project` is created in the `dev-team` namespace.
- The file `users.txt` contains the relevant user details, one user per line, of the form `username = First Last <address@domain.com.au>`, where `username` is the username given in SVN logs.  (See first link in References section for details, in particular answer by user Casey).

### Versions

- subversion version 1.6.17 (r1128011)
- git version 1.9.1
- GitLab version 7.2.1 ff1633f
- Ubuntu server 14.04

### Commands

```bash
git svn clone --stdlayout --no-metadata -A users.txt http://svn.domain.com.au/svn/repository/favourite-project
cd favourite-project
git remote add gitlab git@git.domain.com.au:dev-team/favourite-project.git
git push --set-upstream gitlab master
```

That's it!  Reload the project page in GitLab web UI and you will see all commits and files now listed.

### Notes

- If there are unknown users, the `git svn clone` command will stop, in which case, update `users.txt`, `cd favourite-project` and `git svn fetch` will continue from where it stopped.
- The standard `trunk`-`tags`-`branches` layout for SVN repository is required.
- The SVN URL given to the `git svn clone` command stops at the level immediately above `trunk/`, `tags/` and `branches/`.
- The `git svn clone` command produces a lot of output, including some warnings at the top; I ignored the warnings.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I disagree.  The linked content might change, and the content duplicated here will not be updated, and therefore might be out of date (and in fact I believe it has changed since I originally posted this answer).  The guidelines only say to include some relevant context for a link, which I did -- the actual question was answered wholesale by the link.  Copying the whole linked resource here is not required or necessary.  Was I downvoted for this?!

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend this [short series of screencasts](http://www.tfnico.com/presentations/git-and-subversion) I just discovered. The author walks you through the basic operations, and showcases some more advanced usages.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SourceTree you can do this directly from the app. Goto File -> New/Clone then do the following:

1. Enter the remote SVN URL as the "Source Path / URL".
2. Enter your credentials when prompted.
3. Enter the local folder location as the "Destination path".
4. Give it a name.
5. In the advanced options select "Git" from the dropdown in "Create local
   repository of type".
6. You can optionally specify a revision to clone from.
7. Hit Clone.

Open the repo in SourceTree and you'll see your commit messages have been migrated too.

Now go to Repository -> Repository Settings and add the new remote repo details. Delete the SVN remote if you wish (I did this through the "Edit Config File" option.

Push the code to the new remote repo when you are ready and code freely.

Comment: Thank you.This worked for me.I am using SourceTree and Stash.

Answer (score 2):

As another aside, the git-stash command is a godsend when trying to git with git-svn dcommits.

A typical process:

1. set up git repo
2. do some work on different files
3. decide to check some of the work in, using git
4. decide to `svn-dcommit`
5. get the dreaded "cannot commit with a dirty index" error.

The solution (requires git 1.5.3+):

```
git stash; git svn dcommit ; git stash apply
```

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add my contribution to the Git community. I wrote a simple bash script which automates the full import. Unlike other migration tools, this tool relies on native git instead of jGit. This tool also supports repositories with a large revision history and or large blobs. It's available via github:

https://github.com/onepremise/SGMS

This script will convert projects stored in SVN with the following format:

```
/trunk
  /Project1
  /Project2
/branches
     /Project1
     /Project2
/tags
 /Project1
 /Project2
```

This scheme is also popular and supported as well:

```
/Project1
     /trunk
     /branches
     /tags
/Project2
     /trunk
     /branches
     /tags
```

Each project will get synchronized over by project name:

```
Ex: ./migration https://svnurl.com/basepath project1
```

If you wish to convert the full repo over, use the following syntax:

```
Ex: ./migration https://svnurl.com/basepath .
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple shell script with no dependencies that will convert one or more SVN repositories to git and push them to GitHub.

https://gist.github.com/NathanSweet/7327535

In about 30 lines of script it: clones using git SVN, creates a .gitignore file from SVN::ignore properties, pushes into a bare git repository, renames SVN trunk to master, converts SVN tags to git tags, and pushes it to GitHub while preserving the tags.

I went thru a lot of pain to move a dozen SVN repositories from Google Code to GitHub. It didn't help that I used Windows. Ruby was all kinds of broken on my old Debian box and getting it working on Windows was a joke. Other solutions failed to work with Cygwin paths. Even once I got something working, I couldn't figure out how to get the tags to show up on GitHub (the secret is --follow-tags).

In the end I cobbled together two short and simple scripts, linked above, and it works great. The solution does not need to be any more complicated than that!

Comment: I used this script. After a bit of trail and error, it worked for me. Please be advised that you need [Git 1.8.3+](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt#L155-L156) for this, as --follow-tags is only supported thereafter.

Answer (score 2):

I´m on a windows machine and made a small Batch to transfer a SVN repo with history (but without branches) to a GIT repo by just calling

`transfer.bat http://svn.my.address/svn/myrepo/trunk https://git.my.address/orga/myrepo`

Perhaps anybody can use it. It creates a TMP-folder checks out the SVN repo there with git and adds the new origin and pushes it... and deletes the folder again.

```
@echo off 
SET FROM=%1 
SET TO=%2 
SET TMP=tmp_%random%

echo from:  %FROM% 
echo to:    %TO% 
echo tmp:   %TMP%

pause

git svn clone  --no-metadata --authors-file=users.txt %FROM% %TMP%  
cd %TMP% 
git remote add origin %TO% 
git push --set-upstream origin master


cd .. 
echo delete %TMP% ... 
pause

rmdir /s /q %TMP%
```

You still need the users.txt with your user-mappings like

```
User1 = User One <u.1@xxx.com>
```

Comment: This answer helped me to move all my repositories to BitBucket without problems.

Comment: Glad to hear. I had only experience with Gitea... but tranferred ~~40 repos this way.

Comment: Very nice! Thnx

Comment: warning; I experienced bad charset issues. I recognized this really too late but it took me several hours fixing. Please check that your resulting repo contains the exact(!) expected sources

Answer (score 1):

Converting svn submodule/folder 'MyModule' into git with history without tags nor branches.

- git svn clone --no-metadata
  --trunk=SomeFolder1/SomeFolder2/SomeFolder3/MyModule http://svnhost:port/repo_root_folder/MyModule_temp -A
  C:\cheetah\svn\authors-transform.txt
- git clone MyModule_temp MyModule
- cd MyModule
- git flow init
- git remote set-url origin
  https://userid@stashhost/stash/scm/xyzxyz/MyModule.git
- git push -u origin master
- git push -u origin develop

To retain svn ignore list use the above comments after step 1

Answer (score 1):

First, credit to the answer from @cmcginty. It was a great starting point for me, and much of what I'll post here borrowed heavily from it. However, the repos that I was moving have years of history which led to a few issues following that answer to the letter (hundreds of branches and tags that would need to be manually moved for one; read more later).

So after hours of searching and trial and error I was able to put together a script which allowed me to easily move several projects from SVN to GIT, and I've decided to share my findings here in case anyone else is in my shoes.

<tl;dr> Let's get started

---

First, create an 'Authors' file which will translate basic svn users to more complex git users. The easiest way to do this is using a command to extract all users from the svn repo you are going to move.

```
svn log -q | awk -F '|' '/^r/ {sub("^ ", "", $2); sub(" $", "", $2); print $2" = "$2" <"$2">"}' | sort -u > authors-transform.txt
```

This will produce a file called authors-transform.txt with a line for each user that has made a change in the svn repo it was ran from.

```
someuser = someuser <someuser>
```

Update to include full name and email for git

```
someuser = Some User <someuser@somewhere.com>
```

Now start the clone using your authors file

```
git svn clone --stdlayout --no-metadata -r854:HEAD --authors-file=authors-transform.txt https://somesvnserver/somerepo/ temp
```

- --stdlayout indicates that the svn repo follows the standard /trunk /branches /tags layout
- --no-metadata tells git not to stamp metadata relating to the svn commits on each git commit. If this is not a one-way conversion remove this tag
- -r854:HEAD only fetches history from revision 854 up. This is where I hit my first snag; the repo I was converting had a 'corrupted' commit at revision 853 so it would not clone. Using this parameter allows you to only clone part of the history.
- temp is the name of the directory that will be created to initialize
  the new git repo

This step can take awhile, particularly on a large or old repo (roughly 18 hours for one of ours). You can also use that -r switch to only take a small history to see the clone, and fetch the rest later.

Move to the new directory

```
cd temp
```

Fetch any missing history if you only pulled partial in clone

```
git svn fetch
```

Tags are created as branches during cloning. If you only have a few you can convert them one at a time.

```
git 1.0.0 origin/tags/1.0.0
```

However, this is tedious if you have hundreds of tags, so the following script worked for me.

```
for brname in `git branch -r | grep tags | awk '{gsub(/^[^\/]+\//,"",$1); print $1}'`; do echo $brname; tname=${brname:5}; echo $tname; git tag $tname origin/tags/$tname; done
```

You also need to checkout all branches you want to keep

```
git checkout -b branchname origin/branches/branchname
```

And if you have a lot of branches as well, this script may help

```
for brname in `git branch -r | grep -v master | grep -v HEAD | grep -v trunk | grep -v tags | awk '{gsub(/^[^\/]+\//,"",$1); print $1}'`; do echo $brname; git checkout -b $brname origin/$brname; done
```

This will ignore the trunk branch, as it will already be checked out as master and save a step later deleting the duplicate branch, as well as ignoring the /tags that we already converted.

Now is a good time to take a look at the new repo and make sure you have a **local** branch or tag for anything you want to keep as remote branches will be dropped in a moment.

Ok, now lets clone everything we've checked out to a clean repo (named temp2 here)

```
cd ..
git clone temp temp2
cd temp2
```

Now we'll need to checkout all of the branches one more time before pushing them to their final remote, so follow your favorite method from above.

If you're following gitflow you can rename your working branch to develop.

```
git checkout -b WORKING
git branch -m develop
git push origin --delete WORKING
git push origin -u develop
```

Now, if everything looks good, you're ready to push to your git repository

```
git remote set-url origin https://somebitbucketserver/somerepo.git
git push -u origin --all
git push origin --tags
```

I did run into one final issue which was that Control Freak initially blocked me from pushing tags that I didn't create, so if your team uses Control Freak you may need to disable or adjust that setting for your initial push.

Answer (score 0):

*[Effectively using Git with Subversion](http://www.viget.com/extend/effectively-using-git-with-subversion/)* is a gentle introduction to git-svn. For existing SVN repositories, git-svn makes this super easy. If you're starting a new repository, it's vastly easier to first create an empty SVN repository and then import using git-svn than it is going in the opposite direction. Creating a new Git repository then importing into SVN can be done, but it is a bit painful, especially if you're new to Git and hope to preserve the commit history.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Ruby installer for Windows and install the latest version with it. Add Ruby executables to your path.

- Install svn2git
- Start menu -> All programs -> Ruby -> Start a command prompt with Ruby
- Then type “gem install svn2git” and enter

  **Migrate Subversion repository**
- Open a Ruby command prompt and go to the directory where the files are to be migrated

  Then svn2git http://[domain name]/svn/ [repository root]
- It may take few hours to migrate the project to Git depends on the project code size.
- This major step helps in creating the Git repository structure as mentioned below.

  SVN (/Project_components) trunk     -->      Git master
  SVN (/Project_components) branches  -->  Git branches
  SVN (/Project_components) tags      -->      Git tags

Create the remote repository and push the changes.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub has an importer. Once you've created the repository, you can import from an existing repository, via its URL. It will ask for your credentials if applicable and go from there.

As it's running it will find authors, and you can simply map them to users on GitHub.

I have used it for a few repositories now, and it's pretty accurate and much faster too! It took 10 minutes for a repository with ~4000 commits, and after it took my friend four days!

Answer (score 0):

Several answers here refer to https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git, but for large repositories this can be slow. I had a try using https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git instead which is a tool with exactly the same name but was used to migrate KDE from SVN to Git.

Slightly more work to set it up but when done the conversion itself for me took minutes where the other script spent hours.

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods to achieve this goal. I've tried some of them and found really working one with just git and svn installed on Windows OS.

Prerequisites:

1. git on windows (I've used this one) https://git-scm.com/
2. svn with console tools installed (I've used tortoise svn)
3. Dump file of your SVN repository. 
   `svnadmin dump /path/to/repository > repo_name.svn_dump`

Steps to achieve final goal (move all repository with history to a git, firstly local git, then remote)

1. Create empty repository (using console tools or tortoiseSVN) in directory REPO_NAME_FOLDER
   `cd REPO_NAME_PARENT_FOLDER`, put dumpfile.dump into REPO_NAME_PARENT_FOLDER
2. `svnadmin load REPO_NAME_FOLDER < dumpfile.dump` Wait for this operation, it may be long
3. This command is silent, so open second cmd window : `svnserve -d -R --root REPO_NAME_FOLDER` 
   Why not just use file:///...... ? Cause next command will fail with `Unable to open ... to URL:`, thanks to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300968/4953065
4. Create new folder SOURCE_GIT_FOLDER
5. `cd SOURCE_GIT_FOLDER`
6. git svn clone svn://localhost/ Wait for this operation.

Finally, what do we got?

Lets check our Local repository :

```
git log
```

See your previous commits? If yes - okay

So now you have fully functional local git repository with your sources and old svn history.
Now, if you want to move it to some server, use the following commands :

```
git remote add origin https://fullurlpathtoyourrepo/reponame.git
git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and its refs for the first time
git push -u origin --tags # pushes up any tags
```

In my case, I've dont need tags command cause my repo dont have tags.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I used the following script to read a text file that has a list of all my SVN repositories and convert them to Git, and later use `git clone --bare` to convert to a bare Git repository:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="list.txt"
while IFS= read -r repo_name
do
 printf '%s\n' "$repo_name"
 sudo git svn clone --shared --preserve-empty-dirs --authors-file=users.txt file:///programs/svn/$repo_name
 sudo git clone --bare /programs/git/$repo_name $repo_name.git
 sudo chown -R www-data:www-data $repo_name.git
 sudo rm -rf $repo_name
done <"$file"
```

list.txt has the format:

```
repo1_name
repo2_name
```

And users.txt has the format:

> `(no author) = Prince Rogers <prince.rogers.nelson@payesley.park.org>`

www-data is the Apache web server user, and permission is needed to push changes over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

All in One - shell script for `SVN` to `GIT` Migration. Mention the `GIT` and `SVN` details with placeholder `<>`

```
#!/bin/bash

######## Project name 
PROJECT_NAME="Helloworld"
EMAIL="example mail"

#Credientials Repo
GIT_USER='<git username>'
GIT_PWD='<git password>'
SVN_USER='<svn username>'
SVN_PWD='<svn password>'

######## SVN repository to be migrated # Dont use https - error will be thrown
BASE_SVN="<SVN URL>/Helloworld"

#Organization inside BASE_SVN
BRANCHES="branches"
TAGS="tags"
TRUNK="trunk"

#Credientials
git config --global user.name '<git username>'
git config --global user.password '<git password>'
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'

######## GIT repository to migrate - Ensure already project created in Git
GIT_URL=https://$GIT_USER:$GIT_PWD@<GIT URL>/Helloworld.git

###########################
#### Don't need to change from here
###########################

#Geral Configuration
ABSOLUTE_PATH=$(pwd)
TMP=$ABSOLUTE_PATH/$PROJECT_NAME

#Branchs Configuration
SVN_BRANCHES=$BASE_SVN/$BRANCHES
SVN_TAGS=$BASE_SVN/$TAGS
SVN_TRUNK=$BASE_SVN/$TRUNK

AUTHORS=$PROJECT_NAME"-authors.txt"

echo '[LOG] Starting migration of '$SVN_TRUNK
echo '[LOG] Using: '$(git --version)
echo '[LOG] Using: '$(svn --version | grep svn,)

mkdir $TMP
echo
echo '[DIR] cd' $TMP
cd $TMP

echo
echo '[LOG] Getting authors'
svn --username $SVN_USER --password $SVN_PWD log -q $BASE_SVN | awk -F '|' '/^r/ {sub("^ ", "", $2); sub(" $", "", $2); print $2" = "$2" <"$2"@"$EMAIL">"}' | sort -u >> $AUTHORS

echo
echo '[RUN] git svn clone --authors-file='$AUTHORS' --trunk='$TRUNK' --branches='$BRANCHES' --tags='$TAGS $BASE_SVN $TMP
git svn clone --authors-file=$AUTHORS --trunk=$TRUNK --branches=$BRANCHES --tags=$TAGS $BASE_SVN $TMP

#Not working so no need to mention it
#--stdlayout $PROJECT_NAME
echo
echo '[RUN] svn ls '$SVN_BRANCHES
svn ls $SVN_BRANCHES

echo 
echo 'git branch -a'
git branch -a

echo
echo '[LOG] Getting first revision'
FIRST_REVISION=$( svn log -r 1:HEAD --limit 1 $BASE_SVN | awk -F '|' '/^r/ {sub("^ ", "", $1); sub(" $", "", $1); print $1}' )

echo
echo '[RUN] git svn fetch -'$FIRST_REVISION':HEAD'
git svn fetch -$FIRST_REVISION:HEAD

#Branches and Tags  
echo
echo '[RUN] svn ls '$SVN_BRANCHES
for BRANCH in $(svn ls $SVN_BRANCHES); do
    echo git branch ${BRANCH%/} remotes/svn/${BRANCH%/}
    git branch ${BRANCH%/} remotes/svn/${BRANCH%/}
done

git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short) %(objectname)" refs/remotes/origin/tags | grep -v "@" | cut -d / -f 3- |
while read ref
do
  echo git tag -a $ref -m 'import tag from svn'
  git tag -a $ref -m 'import tag from svn'
done

git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/remotes/origin/tags | cut -d / -f 1- |
while read ref
do
  git branch -rd $ref
done
  
echo
echo 'git tag'
git tag

echo
echo 'git show-ref --tags'
git show-ref --tags

echo
echo '[RUN] git remote add origin '$GIT_URL
git remote add origin $GIT_URL

echo
echo '[RUN] git push'
git push origin --all --force
git push origin --tags

#echo git branch -d -r trunk
#git branch -d -r trunk

git config --global credential.helper cache
echo 'Successful.'
```

- When you run above script, it will fetch branches and tags details from SVN and put it under `.git` folder.
- Crosscheck whether all branches are there in the `SVN` that should be available under this `.git/refs/heads` folder.
- If some branches are missing which was there in `SVN` then do manually copy branches files from `.git/refs/remotes/origin/<branches>` to `.git/refs/heads`
- Only copy branches (including `master`) and ignore if any `tags` or `trunk`.
- Now run the script again. You could see all `branches` and `tags` in git repositories.

Answer (score -1):

## For this, I have used **svn2git** library with the following procedure:

> sudo apt-get install git-core git-svn ruby
>   sudo gem install svn2git
>   svn log --quiet | grep -E "r[0-9]+ \| .+ \|" | cut -d'|' -f2 | sed 's/ //g' | sort | uniq > authors.txt (this command is for mapping the authors)

Above step should be performed in the folder that you are going to convert from svn to git.

> Add one mapping per line in authors.txt like this

```
anand = Anand Tripathi <email_id>
trip = Tripathi Anand <email_id>
```

Create a folder for a new git repository and execute the command below having the path of authors.txt

```
svn2git <svn_repo_path> --nobranches --notags --notrunk --no-minimize-url --username <user_name> --verbose  --authors <author.txt_path>

If no trunk and no tag and branch is present then have to execute the above command else if root is trunk then mention rootistrunk or trunk is present then --trunk <trunk_name>
```

> git remote add origin 
>   git push --all origin  
>   git push --tags origin