# Subversion repository statistics, other than StatSVN?

Tags: svn, project-management, statsvn

Are there other open source/free packages for producing repository statistics for a Subversion repository?

I've tried StatSVN but it seems to be incompatible with the logfiles for Subversion 1.5 and above.

Note, I know that TortoiseSVN has some statistics built into its dialogs and repository browsing code, but this is not what I'm looking for.

What I'm looking for is a tool that can analyze the repository, and its logs, and produce statistics like these:

- Who checked in the most code
- Code growth over time
- Busy files (changed often)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/) does work for Subversion 1.5 and above. See my comment
[on the SourceForge forums](https://sourceforge.net/forum/message.php?msg_id=7400116) concerning a similar issue reported today on the StatSVN forums.

Comment: Hint: Last version StatSVN is 2010-01-01: release of 0.7.0 is released. Recommendation: Don't use SVN in 2023.

Answer (score 17):

Try [SVNPLot](http://code.google.com/p/svnplot) .

Its written in python and doesnot required a 'checkout working copy'. It will be easy to modify.

Disclosure: I am developer of SVNPlot. So possibly my opinion is somewhat biased. :-)

Comment: Have you already installed `matplotlib` and `pysvn` inside a virtualenv? It's giving me slight headaches... Just asking. I'm giving up for now on SVNPlot. I don't have time to deal with pages and pages of install instructions. I may give it a shot again in a few months... ;)

Comment: I'm also having endless headaches trying to get pysvn installed so that I can install svnplot.  Year and a half later and still no dice.

Comment: Disclaimer: I've not yet tried StatSVN or SVNPlot - but cursory due-diligence 7 years on  StatSVN is dead (last commit 2010) SVNPlot is active (https://bitbucket.org/nitinbhide/svnplot/issues - switch filter to "all").  Kudos to @Nitin Bhide for commit(ment)

Comment: Dead, Repository not found. EoL

Answer (score 8):

It seems that some **SVN tools are not updated anymore**:

- [My Python SVN Stats](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpy-svn-stats.berlios/). Latest release 2007.
- [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/). Last release 2010-01-01.
- [SvnCrawler](http://svncrawler.sourceforge.net/). Latest release 2010.
- [SVNPlot](http://thinkingcraftsman.in/pages/projects/projects-svnplot.html). Latest release 2017.
- [SvnStat](http://sourceforge.net/projects/svnstat/). Latest release 2014-09-19.
- [VCS Report](http://vcsreport.sourceforge.net/). Latest release 2006.

One reason might be that these tools are "good enough".

> The "modern" way to go is to [convert the repo to git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/how-to-migrate-svn-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository/3972103#3972103) and then use a [git statistics tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828874/generating-statistics-from-git-repository).

Comment: Good list of historic tools in 2023. Avoid SVN.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across MPY SVN STATS:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mpy-svn-stats.berlios/

It works quite well but the graphs are a bit ugly.

[image: Some stats from MPY SVN STATS]

2017/1/10: Replaced original download link with more recent sourceforge.  MPY-SVN was extremely easy to setup (called python using bash script on win10).  Unlike statsvn.org it does not need a working copy, works from repository url.  Unlike svnplot I was able to get it working on 3 repositories in <5min.

Comment: Hint: Last update 2014, aka historic.

Answer (score -4):

You can try [programeter.com](http://programeter.com). It has free package if you need.

Comment: -1: Their free product integrates with Jira only.

Comment: Website seems to be no longer available. I assume that was a SAAS. Any alternative?