# Is there any tool that will document an SVN repository?

Tags: svn, project-management

I would like to analyze and document one of our svn repositories.  I am looking for the best tool that will make a report based on the log of the svn repository for each revision number tag, branch, etc.  Is there any free/paid tool available for this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882160/subversion-repository-statistics-other-than-statsvn

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered [`StatSVN`](http://www.statsvn.org/)?  From their site:

> StatSVN retrieves information from a
>   Subversion repository and generates
>   various tables and charts describing
>   the project development

It includes reports for things like:

- Timeline for the lines of code
- Lines of code for each developer
- Repository Tags Number of LOC per version.
- Repository tree with file count and lines of code
- Evolution of LOC and the amount of change per day

---

Another worth considering is [`svnplot`](http://code.google.com/p/svnplot/) which reads statistics on the SVN repo into an SQLite database for analysis.  It generates various statistics on its own, but also allows you to make custom queries against the database.

Answer (score 2):

With [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org) you can create a [sparse checkout](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html#tsvn-dug-checkout-depth) of the entire repository, then right-click the working copy folder and click [Revision graph](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-revgraph.html) to get a graphical representation.

Answer (score 1):

You can dump the commit log data in an XML file and then process it further with [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xslt) to generate a report:

```
svn log --XML -v -g http://example.com/repo > commit-log.xml
```