# How to count lines of Java code using IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, metrics

How to count lines of Java code using IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: For repository statistics, you can use [Gitinspector](https://github.com/ejwa/gitinspector).  Source: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1828874/873282

Answer (score 505, accepted):

The [Statistic](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/search?correctionAllowed=true&search=statistic) plugin worked for me.

To install it from Intellij:

> File - Settings - Plugins - Browse repositories... Find it on the list and double-click on it.

Access the 'statistic' toolbar via tabs in bottom left of project
[image: screen capture of statistic toolbar, bottom left]

OLDER VERSIONS: Open statistics window from:

> View -> Tool Windows -> Statistic

Comment: The Statistic plugin works with IntelliJ IDEA 12, and even shows counts and percentages for comment lines and blank lines vs. total lines. Could use a bit more documentation. Launch it via new button that is installed in lower left corner of IntelliJ IDEA window. It has additional settings: File - Settings - (Project Settings) Statistic.

Comment: This still works in IntelliJ 13, just ran it on the EAP version.

Comment: The Statistic plugin provides file counts in addition to line counts. I was unable to find file counts with the Metrics Reloaded plug-in.

Comment: Works fine with Android Studio 0.8.x

Comment: Works fine with IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE. Thanks for this brilliant plugin.

Comment: Well it is a bit annoying I'd like to remove `test` folders, but there's no directory wildcard to exclude

Comment: Unfortunately, IDEA hangs on “Calculating Statistics...”.

Comment: For me it's not working (anymore) on bigger projects (> 15.000 lines of code). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40707683/intellij-idea-statistic-plugin-out-of-memory

Comment: Works on IDEA 2017.2.5, project > 150 kLOC, but does not group counts, no per module / per source folder sums --> mostly useless :-/

Comment: This plugin doesn't work at all in 2018.1. The View -> Tool windows -> Stastistic just shows an empty window.

Comment: @YngvarKristiansen You have to do an initial refresh (top left corner)

Comment: it works with the latest phpstorm (I'm using it only for JS though) in Dec 2018

Comment: @barfuin, "User can select (Project/Module/Package/File) scope using the 'Refresh on selection' button"

Comment: I downloaded the plugin and restarted IntelliJ. No menu option was added under View -> Tool Windows, and while the plugin is installed the Find Action doesn't see anything under "Statistic" other than the plugin itself. I don't think it's compatible with IntelliJ 18.3.

Comment: @garyrush Thanks for feedback. I updated article to indicate new location (using Idea 2020.3), accessed via bottom-left toolbars. See screenshot.

Answer (score 122):

Quick and dirty way is to do a global search for `'\n'`. You can filter it any way you like on file extensions etc.

<kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd></kbd> -> Text to find = `'\n'` -> Find.

Edit: And 'regular expression' has to be checked.

Comment: Yes, but this also searches through all the files that are in your libraries (ie: if you are creating a web application it looks through all the lines of JQuery for example)

Comment: Neat idea but only if you either trim all empty lines first or explicitly want them to be counted.

Comment: +1 Nice solution. Very simply. I like simply solutions like this.

Comment: @MarcelStör Try it with "(.+)\n"

Comment: Searching for regex ".+" works better. It wont miss the last line in the file if it's missing a trailing newline like "\n" or ".+\n" will. It also semantically matches what your searching for better, that is, lines with characters.

Comment: Intellij hung after finding 40k lines : /

Comment: I ended up doing a plain old search for \n, which completed without hanging (the (.+)\n regex caused hanging).

Comment: I cannot see the number of lines. It says "100+ matches in 3+ files" which isn't very helpful. I use IntelliJ IDEA Community 2019.2

Comment: After doing the find, it only shows the number of files.
Click on "Open in Find Window" and expand the "Found occurrences.." to see the number of lines.

Answer (score 55):

In the past I have used the excellently named [MetricsReloaded](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/93-metricsreloaded) plugin to get this information.

You can install it from the JetBrains repository.

Once installed, access via: *Analyze -> Calculate Metrics...*

Comment: Agreed, documentation is needed. How does one activate the plugin once it is installed?

Comment: To answer my own question: Analyize -> Calculate Metrics

Comment: Doesn't work with IntelliJ IDEA 12:
https://github.com/BasLeijdekkers/MetricsReloaded/issues/19

Comment: Works in IDEA 12 now, not found in the repository you need to install via manually downloading.

Comment: The plugin now works correctly with IDEA 13 when installing via the repository.

Comment: Seems does not have support for Methods LOC

Comment: As of 2021.2, it works just fine.

Comment: I was also searching where to start it => In 2021.2 I found it in the menubar in **Code** |  Calculate Metrics (not "Analyze").

Answer (score 39):

Although it is not an IntelliJ option, you could use a simple Bash command (**if** your operating system is Linux/Unix). Go to your source directory and type:

```
find . -type f -name '*.java' | xargs cat | wc -l
```

Comment: I would do `find . -type f -name '*.java' | xargs cat | wc -l` (quoting the `*.java` part). Otherwise, the shell environment might expand the `*.java` too early and the command won't work properly.

Comment: This will return too many lines. Empty lines should not be counted

Comment: ignore blank lines: `find . -type f -name '*.java' | xargs cat | grep -ve '^\s*$' | wc -l`

Answer (score 25):

Just like Neil said:

> <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd></kbd> -> Text to find = `'\n'` -> Find.

With only one improvement, if you enter `"\n+"`, you can search for non-empty lines

If lines with only whitespace can be considered empty too, then you can use the regex `"(\s*\n\s*)+"` to not count them.

Comment: This is really slow, use only if there's no better way. I recommend installing GitBash and using the `find`.

Answer (score 14):

[Statistic](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=4509) plugins works fine!

Here is a quick case:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and serach for "Statistic" to open the panel.
2. You will see panel as the screenshot and then click `Refresh` for whole project or select your project or file and  `Refresh on selection` for only selection.

[image: statistic]

Answer (score 5):

now 2 versions of metricsreloaded available. One supported on v9 and v10 isavailable here
http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=93

Comment: Doesn't work with IntelliJ IDEA 12: https://github.com/BasLeijdekkers/MetricsReloaded/issues/19

Answer (score 3):

You can to use Count Lines of Code ([CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/))

On `Settings` -> `External Tools` add a new tool

- Name: Count Lines of Code
- Group: Statistics
- Program: path/to/cloc
- Parameters: $ProjectFileDir$ or $FileParentDir$

Answer (score 1):

To find all including empty lines of code try @Neil's solution:

Open *Find in Path* (<kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd></kbd>)

Search for the following regular expression: `\n'`

For lines with at least one character use following expression:

```
(.+)\n
```

For lines with at least one word character or digit use following expression:

```
`(.*)([\w\d]+)(.*)\n`
```

Notice: But the last line of file is just counted if you have a line break after it.