# How to count lines of code (LOC) using IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: lua, intellij-idea

title says everything plus:
- development language Lua
- code revision control system - Perforce (integrated with IntelliJ IDE)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435581/how-to-count-lines-of-java-code-using-intellij-idea

Comment: You should change the accepted answer, even @duffymo
 the author of the currently accepted answer says so in the comments below.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can either turn on the display of lines of code for a single file by right clicking in the left gutter and highlighting "display lines of code".  Or you can do it for your entire project by downloading the [Statistic plug-in](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=4509).  It's very nice indeed, because it shows LOC and other metrics for your entire project.

Comment: The Statistic plug-in also counts every line in the branch/tags folder, even if they are excluded from the project.

Comment: I don't know what "excluded from the project" means.  When I check out a project I do it in such a way that only that branch or tag is visible to IntelliJ.  That's the only way that makes sense to me.

Comment: For large multi-module project you may want to have the branches and tags checked out to quickly be able to switch between them. Each sub-module has a trunk/branch. The plugin seems to choose the project root directory and count all the files contained within, disregarding whether or not that subfolder is actually used in the project at all. There is a feature in IntelliJ where you can "Mark Directory As/Excluded" from the workspace manually but the plugin doesn't seem to use this information at all.

Comment: I've installed the plugin but how option in the menu can I use to bring the statistics dialog up?

Comment: Go to View->Tool Windows->Statistic.  I'm running it in IntelliJ 16.

Answer (score 76):

You can hack it via the native, global search:

1. Ctrl + Shift + F (to open global search)
2. Use regex mode (check "regex" checkbox)
3. In the searchbox, enter only a caret "^" (without the quotes)
4. You *may* want to limit the search to a specific directory, via the "directory" tab
5. Hit the "Open in Find Window" button on the bottom-right
6. If it asks whether you want to continue, press "Continue"

Notes:

- In regex, the caret (^) denotes the start of a line, except when inside square brackets, in which case it denotes negation
- If you wanted to count non-empty lines, you could instead use "`^.*\S`" (without quotes), which signifies "The start of a line (^), followed by any number of characters (except newline) (.*), followed by a non-whitespace character (\S)"

[image: Gloabal search for Lines of Code]

Comment: Had this answer shown up 8 years earlier it would have been the accepted answer.

Comment: just quick and easy, amazing, thank you so much !!

Comment: Eight years later.  I'd accept this answer, too.  I don't use the statistics plugin anymore, but I do use this answer.