# IntelliJ Idea 11 - How to count lines of code(LOC)?

Tags: ide, intellij-idea, lines-of-code

There is an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435581/how-to-count-lines-of-java-code-using-intellij-idea) about it, I just tried **Statics plugin** as some people mentioned, but I couldn't find anything associated with it after Idea restart. Does anyone knows a way(plugin, etc..) to count lines of code(LOC) using **IntelliJ Idea 11**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to count lines of Java code using IntelliJ IDEA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435581/how-to-count-lines-of-java-code-using-intellij-idea)

Comment: no if you look my description, I have already mentioned this old question. This question is specific for IntelliJ Idea **11** which is newer than the question that you mentioned above.

Comment: hey that plugin is weird it didn't work for me either, then I just restared IDEA (or computer) couple of times and it started to work. not very deterministic approach though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

View -> Tool Windows -> Statistic

I was also searching for this a while.