# Retrieve the amount of lines in a Flex project

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flash-builder4.5

This might sound useless, but just for the sake of information (and for fun to be honest :) )

Is there a way to find in Flash Builder the amount of lines written in a Flex project?

Comment: you can do that with other tools as well... you can even write an app in AIR to do that.... but to answer: No! in Flash builder there is not such a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good answer here on how to do the same with IntelliJ and Java:  [How to count lines of Java code using IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435581/how-to-count-lines-of-java-code-using-intellij-idea)

where the 'Find In Project' feature is used.   For IntelliJ this is:

```
Ctrl+Shift+F -> Text to find = '\n+' -> Find
```

The search must be set to find based on a regular expression.  '\n+' indicates to look for lines that are not empty

So you can adopt this method to FlashBuilder / Eclipse - I am sure it will have a similar feature.  Try Ctrl+H.

Alternatively, load your Flex project into IntelliJ.

Comment: Love this trick :) I forgot to check "Regular expression" at first, it is now working like a charm. Thank you.