# Using Statistic plugin for IntelliJIDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, lines-of-code

I am trying to count the lines of code in my project in IntelliJIDEA. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435581/how-to-count-lines-of-java-code-using-intellij-idea)
I saw that Statistic plugin is good for that. But I do not know how to use it. Can someone tell me that please? Please direct me to documentation if there is.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should click `View -> Tool Windows -> Statistic` and in the bottom of IDE you have something like this.[image: this]

You may also consider using standalone tools such as [cloc](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Is there a way to show file.txt? Same as the Java files.