# GIT - who pushed/wrote most code

Tags: git, github

Is there a git command to check which developer pushed the most code for all history?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828874/generating-statistics-from-git-repository

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: Blame Statistics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589731/git-blame-statistics)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found something ,

```
git ls-files | xargs -n1 -d'\n' -i git-blame {} | perl -n -e '/\s\((.*?)\s[0-9]{4}/ && print "$1\n"' | sort -f | uniq -c -w3 | sort -r
User: askedrelic
Functions: perl sort uniq xargs
```

> Prints per-line contribution per author for a GIT repository
>
> Figures out total line contribution per author for an entire GIT repo. Includes binary files, which kind of mess up the true count.
>
> If crashes or takes too long, mess with the ls-file option at the start:
>
> `git ls-files -x "*pdf" -x "*psd" -x "*tif" to remove really random binary files`
>
> `git ls-files "*.py" "*.html" "*.css" to only include specific file types`
>
> Based off my original SVN version: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2787/prints-total-line-count-contribution-per-user-for-an-svn-repository

http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3889/prints-per-line-contribution-per-author-for-a-git-repository

Comment: It's deprecated, any update ?

Answer (score 3):

LWN publish ["Who wrote 2.6.x"](http://lwn.net/Articles/420658/) reports for the Linux kernel using a tool called [gitdm](http://lwn.net/Articles/290957/)

I've had some success using it for other projects too, it's especially useful if you want to compare the contributions of different groups of developers based on employer.

Answer (score 2):

Github provides impact graphs. For example, [here's the graph for comex/frash](https://github.com/comex/frash/graphs/impact).

Comment: This feature is gone. The above link throws a 410

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Windows and use TortoiseGit, you can select **Show Log** for a repo. In the dialog coming up, select **Statistics**:
[image: tortoisegit_screenshot]

Now you can select either raw **Statistics**, **Commits by author** and **Commits by date** from the drop down box in the upper right corner:

[image]

Comment: Use alt+printscreen to copy a screenshot of just the current window to your clipboard.

Comment: @The Guy Of Doom: I know that. I actually used that to capture the windows. But that doesn't anonymize the images and highlights what I want to show. Therefore, I have to invest some little more work...

Comment: ah, ok. I thought you didn't, as I see some borders :D

Comment: @The Guy Of Doom: now that you're telling, I can see them too. This is odd: when I paste into `paint`, there are no borders but when pasting into `Gimp` using `CTRL-SHIFT-V`, the borders appear. Strange stuff. When I capture the screen directrly through `Gimp`, no borders again... Good to know.

Comment: Looks like the GIMP shifts the image to the right X number of pixels, wrapping them around and displaying the lost pixels on the left...

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in [Determine current code distribution by author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239834/determine-current-code-distribution-by-author), you can easily produce that statistics using [gitdm](https://www.gitorious.org/mining-tools/gitdm).