# graphs for changes amount of git repo

Tags: git, time, graph

Hi
Is there a program to show changes amount graph of a git repository? Specifically a graph that shows these varibales:

- number of total lines in the course of time (one point for every commit)
- speed of adding lines (one point between every two commits)
- speed of removing/modifying lines (one point between every two commits)

Something like [this graph for Linux kernel](http://www.linuxfordevices.com/images/stories/lf_whowriteslinux_code_chart_sm.jpg)

I wish there was a graphical tool. Or a tool that gives image as output (bitmap or vector).
Or at least there was an easy way to get data for that graphs to use in a spreadsheet program like OpenOfficeCalc or Exel.

Comment: You could get this data with `git diff --stat commit1 commit2`. You will probably need a script to gather the numbers there for a predefined set of commits (or tags) and extract the numbers...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828874/generating-statistics-from-git-repository

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that I know of:

The only graphical stats generator for Git is **[gitstats](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/)**, which produces graphs [like those for Linux](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/examples/linux-2.6/activity.html).

[image: commit per hours]

Worth checking out: **[pepper](http://scm-pepper.sourceforge.net/)**

> Pepper is a flexible command-line tool for retrieving statistics and generating reports from source code repositories.
>   It ships with several graphical and textual reports, and is easily extendable using the Lua scripting language. pepper includes support for multiple version control systems, including Git and Subversion.

They have a [neat gallery](http://scm-pepper.sourceforge.net/gallery/).

---

Update April 2013: for GitHub projects, you also have now **[Pulse](https://github.com/zmoazeni/csscss/pulse)** (see "[Get up to speed with Pulse](https://github.com/blog/1476-get-up-to-speed-with-pulse)")

> Pulse is a great way to discover recent activity on projects.
>   Maybe you haven't checked on  your favorite repository in a while or you just discovered a project that looks interesting to you. 
>   **Pulse will show you who has been actively committing and what has changed in a project's default branch**:

[image: Pulse]

**You can find the link to the left of the nav bar**.

[image: Link]