# Is there a way to generate metrics for a GitHub project?

Tags: github, metrics

I've several GithHub projects and I wanted to know the metrics of these projects.

Is there a tool to generate metrics for a given GitHub project? Even very basic metrics like LOC would be enough (even though more complete metrics would be appreciated).

I just discovered that there was a great service, Caliper, doing that, but that has been closed. Is there another services of this kind?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/6610525/873282

Comment: Annoying that such a useful question has been closed. How do I vote to reopen?

Comment: You should have a look to repoXplorer (https://github.com/morucci/repoxplorer). This is an open source project able to compute stats for a project (a group of git repositories) as well as for a contributor and a group of contributors. It provides a REST interface and a web UI. Best is to have a look to the demo instance (ex: stats for the kubernetes project here https://repoxplorer-demo.okombu.com/project.html?pid=kubernetes)

Comment: Also this question is related and not closed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610525/how-to-generate-stats-for-a-github-project

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found two solutions:

- [ohloh](https://www.ohloh.net/): you can put your project on the site and it will analyze your source code and provide some interesting statistics
- [GitStats](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/): a simple statistics generator for any Git repository on your computer

Answer (score 4):

`git log`

options (some or one of)

> --stat[=width[,name-width]]
>
> Generate a diffstat. You can override the default output width for
>   80-column terminal by --stat=width. The width of the filename part can
>   be controlled by giving another width to it separated by a comma.
>
> --numstat
>
> Similar to --stat, but shows number of added and deleted lines in
>   decimal notation and pathname without abbreviation, to make it more
>   machine friendly. For binary files, outputs two - instead of saying 0
>   0.
>
> --shortstat
>
> Output only the last line of the --stat format containing total number
>   of modified files, as well as number of added and deleted lines.

Comment: This works but only for per-commit stats. My goal is to have per-repository stats.

Comment: @BaptisteWicht - `git log [<options>] [<since>..<until>] [[--] <path>...]` - use **full range of changeset without file-path restriction**, just *use it*