# How to see statistics of a repository on Github

Tags: github

Previously I remember that I could go into any repository and see how many codes it has how many lines with or without comments, what languages is it made of with how much percentage, how many man hour was used for development of that repository. I could see all of them on my browser. No code was required.

Now, I cannot find any option on Github. Is this facility changed, moved or removed?

Comment: Do you mean these -> https://github.com/django/django/graphs/commit-activity ?

Comment: also, underneath the box with "X commits, Y branches, Z releases, W contributors" you have a color bar. if you press on it you get the language statistics.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610525/how-to-generate-stats-for-a-github-project/31344479#31344479

Comment: @redaxmedia thank you very much. however, I still remember that I went into chromium repo and I could see how many man-hour was used to build that and in what languages are their file written and how much percent for how many language. Are those fascilities from github gone?

Comment: @redaxmedia that url returns 404

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source project made by @vdaubry : [Github Awards](http://github-awards.com/)

You can get all the information you described and more.