# Visualize Git logs to people who don't understand version control

Tags: git, version-control

I need to somehow visualize a project with graphs, commits, some analysis, etc. Stuff that people (who don't know terms like "version control" or "git" - i.e. illiterate people in that domain) that this project has required XYZ amount of work measured in X, Y, Z. Indicators, in other words. ZYZ amount of developers where Z correspond language P of proportion %%, language T of proportion, etc.

How can I explain in a hectic situation a bit of a technical project to managers XYZ objectively without reinventing the wheel? I am a bit fed up explaining things again-and-again-and-again and things do not proceed because they do not understand the issues at all. If I could get some automatic log summary or PDF or RSS or something like that, they may understand things better. We are currently using Flowdock where our logs appear in real-time but even with it, they want more details (they can only see the log msgs). But without looking at the repo they cannot see much else.

Any automatic repository visualizer or something like that?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828874/generating-statistics-from-git-repository

Comment: Perhaps related [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/138084/how-to-visualise-git-commits-on-a-video-like-a-process), make it good-looking and visual!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github has some visual guides like impact, punchcard etc.

See the rubinius example: https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/graphs/impact

Comment: ...any idea whether the things such as impact, puchcard etc are available with Bitbucket.org? They help communication.

Answer (score 0):

Attlasian Fisheye would give you lines of code sort of stuff, but that is of course a somewhat dangerous metric to hand to your business folks since occasionally deleting a huge messy section of code and replacing it with clean efficient code is very valuable.

I'm not sure there is a good answer, because the problem lies with your managers not understanding programming (from the sound of it)

Maybe a better one is an agile planning tool that has cards and stories and tasks for them to track and burn down graphs that they can put in their reports.