# Git "accounting"

Tags: git, version-control, accounting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating statistics from Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828874/generating-statistics-from-git-repository)

I'm interested in doing some accounting on a git repository with multiple contributors, something akin to github's statistics.  Is anyone aware of something similar that could be used on the command line to get some simple stats of committers, number of lines changed, number of new tags, branches, and accompanying dates?  I know I can role my own, but I wondered what other folks do along these lines.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/ for this. Rather plain output but useful.