# Git blobless repository

Tags: git, metadata, git-fetch, git-notes

I'm wondering if there's a way to get commit and tree objects only from a remote.

This may sound like a silly question, I'm not sure—I'm new to git plumbing. I'm building an app that associates meta-data with git commits, authorships, and file system structure. My options are to build a cludgy in-database normalization of the data with some sort of hook-enabled syncing mechanism, or to use the powerful native git tools for syncing, attaching metadata, and querying history.

However, since I don't actually need the blob objects, it'd save me a buck or two on hosting if I could shed them somehow. Is this or any incarnation of the concept possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating statistics from Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828874/generating-statistics-from-git-repository)

Comment: There are definitely git-statistics options out there; tools I might myself use. I also need to handle my own data and `git-notes` is one approach I'm currently exploring. Scenario aside, this is a very explicit question unrelated to git statistics or other questions I've been able to find: Can you get only certain types of git object (say commit and tree) from a remote?

Comment: An example of an alternate incarnation of this concept might involve subverting `git-fast-import` to only grab certain types of object from a remote. I'm not sure if it would allow you do this without getting the blobs, but it demonstrates well exactly what I want to know: high-level, can you have commit and tree objects without blobs, and low-level, what git plumbing command would allow me to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today, git has "partial clone" options that enable downloading the commits and trees of a repository without its blobs. You can do it by passing `--filter=blob:none` to the `git clone` command. This does require the remote you are cloning from to have a new enough git version to support the filter protocol.

See also:

- [git clone docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---filterltfilter-specgt)
- [Get up to speed with partial clone and shallow clone](https://github.blog/2020-12-21-get-up-to-speed-with-partial-clone-and-shallow-clone/)

Comment: This is exactly what I wished I'd had in 2013, updating to be the new answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, a commit object only *names* a tree object, and then the tree object (once found) names more trees and blobs.  Thus, a git repository in which all the blob object files were deliberately "broken" (e.g., overwritten with an empty file, or even removed entirely) would work to some degree—in fact, to the same degree that it does if you create such a thing manually:

```
$ chmod +w .git/objects/f7/0d6b139823ab30278db23bb547c61e0d4444fb
$ : > .git/objects/f7/0d6b139823ab30278db23bb547c61e0d4444fb
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ git cat-file -p HEAD:file
error: object file .git/objects/f7/0d6b139823ab30278db23bb547c61e0d4444fb is empty
fatal: Not a valid object name HEAD:file
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error: object file .git/objects/f7/0d6b139823ab30278db23bb547c61e0d4444fb is empty
error: sha1 mismatch f70d6b139823ab30278db23bb547c61e0d4444fb
error: f70d6b139823ab30278db23bb547c61e0d4444fb: object corrupt or missing
missing blob f70d6b139823ab30278db23bb547c61e0d4444fb
```

Clearly it sort-of-works.  (In fact, `git cat-file -p HEAD` and `git cat-file -p HEAD:` also work here, as does `git ls-tree -r HEAD`.)

The problem you're going to run into immediately is that git prefers to store objects in packs, and transfer packs around, and those will notice the corrupted (or missing, if you `rm` them) objects.  It might not even save that much space, depending on how compressed the objects are in the packs (it's been observed that the repo is sometimes smaller than the checked-out tree!).

Comment: I suspected having **no** blobs might prove problematic (just finished browsing the `git-pack-objects` man). [This post](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/practical-git-1-manage-repository-that-metadata-only/) notes that having the `.git` database *only* allows for useful querying. If I could fetch that *only* it would definitely save a little space, but as you point out, the tree can be heavier that the project itself.

Comment: Any `--bare` repo omits the work-tree.  You can clone a work tree to a new `--bare` repo; in fact, at previous $workplace that was the first step in our standard setup process.

Comment: That's what I've been doing toying with this proof-of-concept. I'm increasingly on the fence with this approach–I'm loathe to create a SQL database with complicated syncing rules just to attach my metadata when git has an elegant, easy-to-sync file-driven database to do so, and I want full access to the repo history. But I can't help but feel that to do so would hurt my scalability as the project grew. I'd love to hear your thoughts on the matter, but you've definitely answered my question here: no, not without corrupting the object DB and making future pulls impossible.

Comment: I think you'd be better off storing your copy of commit data along with the raw SHA-1 value.  Since SHA-1s are immutable you can always query the git DB (fetched and then removed again if space is an issue, or write a protocol that allows extracting data by SHA-1 a la various web interfaces that already do this), asking it where heads and tags are and then following SHA-1 values through commit graphs.  Once you reach one you already have, you can stop following that thread.