# Git commit stats per file

Tags: git

I want to get all commit info for every author, but I want to do this per file. I am a bit lost with the `git` documentation. Anyone know how to go about this? I want to do this for a certain period of time, for example for 2014-2016.

Comment: If you're looking for git command to do all of that at once, it doesn't exist, but some opensource projects can calculate that kind of statistics. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828874/generating-statistics-from-git-repository for example

Comment: @SimonPA I am interested in those kind of frameworks as well. I am just trying to get some data.

Comment: `git blame` is probably your best start for a porcelain command, and you might be interested in taking a look at http://gource.io

Comment: @dimitris93 http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/ is the only one i tried yet. But you can find what you need. The "per file" part might be done by bash loop if it's not in it.

Answer (score 1):

If by *"all commit info"* you mean commits history, then `git log --since <date> --until <date> <file_path>` will do the job.

You can also filter commits made by certain author using `--author` option.