# svn - getting line modification statistics

Tags: svn, statsvn

I'm trying to get a report going which shows the individual diff-stats per commit (ie. lines added, modified and deleted). CVS had this.

Is there a way to get this from SVN?

I've tried:

```
svn log --xml -v -r HEAD:234234
```

But it only shows commit comments, and the files that were added, modified and deleted. I need lines added, modified, and deleted.

How does a tool like StatSVN get this kind of information to present this kind of report?

I'd like to use a tool, but can't (for reasons I beyond my control).

Comment: Possible answer from http://stackoverflow.com/q/882160/438636

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll have to fetch the diffs (with [svn diff](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re09.html)) and count the lines yourself (that's what StatSVN does: obviously, it calculates the counts once for each commit and then saves it so that it doesn't have to calculate it over and over).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to do it with svn itself we use [svn plot](http://code.google.com/p/svnplot/) for this over here. These graph are not very detailed but give a good picture.