# git-svn clone fails unexpectedly

Tags: git, git-svn

I run the following:

```
git svn clone --stdlayout --no-metadata -A users.txt -r 3760:4662 svn://kumquat.geoplan.ufl.edu/Projects/S4-Geocoding S4-Geocoding-SVN.git
```

It begins running and runs fine for a while, then bombs:

```
...
        M       S4.Geocoding.Client/App.xaml.cs
        M       S4.Geocoding.Client/MainPage.xaml.cs
        M       S4.Geocoding.Client/CodingPage.xaml
        M       S4.Geocoding.Client/CodingPage.xaml.cs
r4163 = 498dad8ce3730390393fc13b183fdbbff7108e6b (refs/remotes/trunk)
        M       S4.Geocoding.Client/CodingPage.xaml.cs
r4164 = 728b706b27d60d91659c144c3fac98cdbd1b09b2 (refs/remotes/trunk)
Found possible branch point: svn://kumquat.geoplan.ufl.edu/Projects/S4-Geocoding/trunk => svn://kumquat.geoplan.ufl.edu/Projects/S4-Geocoding/branches/auto-advance-crash-report-viewer, 4160
Use of uninitialized value $u in substitution (s///) at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 1728.
Use of uninitialized value $u in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 1728.
refs/remotes/trunk: 'svn://kumquat.geoplan.ufl.edu' not found in ''
```

What could be going on? I don't know where to start to troubleshoot this.

Comment: removing the `--no-metadata` flag solved this

Comment: "Use of uninitialized value" implies this is a genuine Git bug to me. That said, if you found a fix that worked, make it obvious by adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As me_and suggests, this is probably a Git bug. After poking around the source code, it appeared that the problem was related to metadata. I was able to work around it by removing the `--no-metadata` flag.

Answer (score 2):

As illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37048201/6309) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3011403/6309), passing a bad trunk (becuse of a non-standard svn structure) will cause this error.

Git 2.9 will be less verbose (will die quicker).
See [commit 523a33c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/523a33ca17c76bee007d7394fb3930266c577c02) (07 May 2016) by [Christian Couder (`chriscool`)](https://github.com/chriscool).
<sup>(Merged by [Eric Wong -- `ele828` --](https://github.com/ele828) in [commit 523a33c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/523a33ca17c76bee007d7394fb3930266c577c02), 08 May 2016)</sup>

> ### Git/SVN: die when there is no commit metadata
>
> When passing a bad `--trunk` option to `git svn clone`, like for example the same URL that we are cloning.
>
> Let's fix that by just die()ing when we have an uninitialized value because we cannot get commit metadata from a ref.

That avoids all the additional error messages like:

```
Found possible branch point...
Use of uninitialized value $u in substitution (s///) at...
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried `git svn clone --no-metadata $repo` on my Windows Visual Studio Code/Terminal Panel and got the similar error.

In the end, issue is gone if I run this git-svn-clone command on PowerShell.