# what i can do after git svn clone fails?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, centos, git-svn

my issue is not the same as this [git-svn clone fails unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398415/git-svn-clone-fails-unexpectedly), since it can be solved by remove --no-metadata option, i have no such option in my command, my commad is simply as:

```
git svn clone -s svn://xxx.xxx
```

times amd times again, i failed to clone code from svn repo:(
the error message is as follows:

```
r506 = 82a01de65882f5bd800aca5a6f3556ba940ea3f5 (refs/remotes/trunk)
Found possible branch point: svn://svn.nginx.org/nginx/trunk => svn://svn.nginx.org/nginx/tags/release-0.1.27, 506
Found branch parent: (refs/remotes/tags/release-0.1.27) 82a01de65882f5bd800aca5a6f3556ba940ea3f5
Following parent with do_switch
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/SVN/Core.pm line 584.
Network connection closed unexpectedly:  at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 3136


real    8m13.819s
user    0m24.079s
sys     0m44.250s
[root@home git-test]# echo $?
1
```

what i can do after i fails to clone code from svn repo:(
start from the beginning? and fail again?
why this happens, is this the problem of git, svn, or git-svn?

Comment: Is there a possibility you have some read access issue (svn not allowing you to access some part of the repo), a bit like in http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=486527 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying a limited number of revisions with the `--revision` parameter. You most likely do not need the whole history, especially if the project has a long history.

From the manual page:

> This allows revision ranges for partial/cauterized history to be supported. $NUMBER, $NUMBER1:$NUMBER2 (numeric ranges), $NUMBER:HEAD, and BASE:$NUMBER are all supported.

So for example `--revision 3000:HEAD` would fetch revisions starting from r3000.

Comment: what --revision means, if i set --revision to be 3000, then all history before 3000 is just ignored, right?