# why git-svn failed with signal 13?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

it is confusing that i failed for many times to clone a svn repo using git svn, why?

```
$ git svn clone -s https://192.168.2.145/svn/myprojects/Search/

Following parent with do_switch
Successfully followed parent
r362 = 6be745be496f98f96ac66fccead8211734cf6455 (refs/remotes/tags/8-22)
Found possible branch point: https://192.168.2.145/svn/myprojects/demo/trunk => https://192.168.2.145/svn/myprojects/Search/trunk, 368
Initializing parent: refs/remotes/trunk@368
**error: git-svn died of signal 13**


$ echo $?
141
```

Answer (score 8):

Following [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/171365), it seems to be a rather peculiar (and unsolved) bug.

> I managed to get a lot farther with

```
while ! git svn fetch ; do sleep 1 ; done
```

> But eventually I exceeded my disk quota.
>
> I've run into this in my `git-svn clones` as well. It happened once last year.
>   I tried this trick I found googling around:

```
rm -f .git/index
git read-tree --reset HEAD
git status
```

> ... but it didn't help.
>   I ended up re-doing the `git svn clone`. Since then it has worked fine.

Comment: Repeating the `git svn fetch` a couple of times finished the clone for me.

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation to shadowhome's answer to suppress stdout so errors are more visible and this grammar works with zsh.

```
while true ; do git svn fetch > /dev/null && break ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

My git svn clone command failed with this error, but a git svn fetch (as suggested by others) failed with:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I re-ran

```
git svn clone <svn-repo> --no-metadata -s <repo dir>
```

And the clone continued as normal.  Until I hit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398415/git-svn-clone-fails-unexpectedly) bug and am now restarting without the --no-metadata flag

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this with a very large svn repo, ended up doing this after the initial git svn clone failed with this same error.

while [ `echo $?` -ne "0" ] ;do git svn fetch ; done

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when using Ruby 1.9.1 upgrading to Ruby 2 fixed this issue for me.