# svn2git failing saying Author: VisualSVN Server not defined in ./authors.txt file

Tags: git, svn

I am trying to migrate to git from svn and it fails by throwing the below error:

```
sethu@csmartserver:~/csmart/git/csmart$ sudo /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/svn2git http://localhost/svn/csmart --authors ./authors.txt --verbose
Running command: git svn init --prefix=svn/ --no-metadata --trunk=trunk --tags=tags --branches=branches http://localhost/svn/csmart
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_IN:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_IN"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Running command: git config --local svn.authorsfile ./authors.txt
Running command: git svn fetch 
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_IN:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_IN"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Author: VisualSVN Server not defined in ./authors.txt file

command failed:
2>&1 git svn fetch
```

My authors.txt file is of the below format:

```
jdoe = John Doe <joh.doe@gmail.com>
```

Could anyone help understand how to fix this issue please?

Comment: And... Is `VisualSVN Server` in `authors.txt`?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You could use SmartGit to check out your SVN repository and push that clone to you Git server.

Answer (score 31):

Just ran into this. For svn2git, you'll need to add a line in your Authors file like follows:

```
VisualSVN Server = Visual SVN Server <admin@yourdomain.com>
```

Comment: Be sure to use notepad (or the simplest text editor you can) -- others may auto-wrap the text

Comment: I have added "VisualSVN Server = Visual SVN Server <name.secondname@mycompany.com>" but the error persists.  Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 7):

The solution that worked for me:
Encoding of the authors-transform file on Windows must be "UFT-8 without BOM".

Just use some smart editor that can do the convertion.

Comment: Thanks! After converting the encoding using notepad++ the authors.txt could be read correctly.

For those using the [svn-migration-scripts](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/svn-migration-scripts/): running the command `java -jar svn-migration-scripts.jar authors https://subversion.server.net/svn/myrepo > authors.txt` in powershell creates a file with encoding UFT-8-bom

Answer (score 1):

I would skip that script altogether unless it does something you need

Assuming your repo has the normal `trunk/ branches/ tags/` layout

```
mkdir csmart
cd csmart
git svn init http://localhost/svn/csmart
git svn fetch
```

Ought to do the trick

Comment: Thanks.. with that I have the repository. How do I add the users though?

Comment: I don't know what you mean "Add the users" with git the access control and the repo are somewhat less linked than with svn.

You could give them access to the repo or use something like gitosis

Comment: Actually after doing this the repository was empty with no files in it. Instead I tried git svn clone http://localhost/svn/csmart -s and this got me all the data. I then created a bare repository clone out of this and used that to get the files over to every other system in the office. But this does not have any branches that were exiting in SVN? What happened to them? Doesn't this create git branches for the svn ones?

Comment: You probably want the --stdlayout option

Comment: I still get Author: VisualSVN Server not defined in "C:/Code Test/Git/ConvertedSVN/authors.txt" file when I fetch?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to install SubGit on the server. It has better translation engine than git-svn/svn2git that preserves  more SVN concepts like ignores, EOLs, etc. There's an [article](http://blog.subgit.com/visualsvn-subversion-server-and-git/) how to do that step-by-step.