# Subversion -> Git migration: git clone not making a full clone?

Tags: git, svn, migration

I've been following the Subversion -> Git migration guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3972103/1107232

I'm migrating from Subversion 1.7.3 to git 1.7.9.2. I have one SVN repository with 9 projects in it, and after I run the command:

```
$ sudo git svn clone -stdlayout --no-metadata --authors-file=/var/git/svnauthors.txt file:///var/subversion /var/git/temp-repo

$ sudo git svn fetch

$ git branch -r
2.1.3
2.1.3@10
2.1.3@11
2.1.3@14
2.1.3@15
trunk
trunk@12
```

I get a 36M /var/git/temp-repo folder, but my /var/subversion folder is 606M.

Running 'git checkout -b 2.1.3 2.1.3' just prints 'Switched to a new branch '2.1.3''
Do I need to add some file:///var/subversion paths or something?

Comment: Is the only "problem" you've noticed the size of the repo?

Comment: Did you read the part about how svn branches need to be manually created in order to clone them?

Comment: Also if the size is the only issue keep in mind if the size youre comparing is the actual svn repository folder thats going to be alot bigger the git. If anything you should be comparing the size of an svn checkout of the repo to the git repo, but i think even then the sizes will be different.

Comment: BTW Why do you run git as root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was only getting one branch, I needed all the others in addition to the tags which someone helped me with in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606675/migrate-from-subversion-to-git-clone-all-branches-and-push-through-gitolite)