# Migrate SVN-Repositories into Gitblit

Tags: git, svn, gitblit

we would like to change from svn to git. We have a svn-server in our intranet and would like to have the equivalent for git.

[gitblit](http://gitblit.com/index.html) seems interesting to use because there is tomcat running on our server.

So, what's the easiest way to migrate all the repositories from svn?

One way I could think of is the following:

1. migrate each repository somewhere to a git client ([something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/how-to-migrate-svn-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository))
2. create the git-repo on gitblit
3. push to gitblit

Should we go for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plan sounds reasonable. We had the same situation. 
Here are some questions you need to answer:

1. Is your svn repository complying to the standard layout for branches/tags/trunk? If not, you might restructure your svn repository prior to converting to git.
2. How much history do you need in the git repository. I suggest you run svn clone from a recent revision (e.g. `git svn clone -r 1234`) and set the svn repository to read-only.