# git svn returns empty repository

Tags: macos, git, svn

I am trying to move my ~6GB local subversions repository to git and keep all history.

```
$ git svn clone --stdlayout --no-metadata -A /Users/dominikwilkowski/Desktop/users.txt file://localhost/Users/dominik/repository/svn/sites /Users/dominik/repository/git/sites
```

This command will run without error or feeedback at all and will end up creating an empty repository.

My svn version is:

```
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.7.8 (r1419691)
   compiled Dec 13 2012, 15:48:59

Copyright (C) 2012 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people; see the NOTICE
file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_neon : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using Neon.
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
* ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
```

and my git version:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)
```

I am using [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/) as my new git client and [versions](http://www.versionsapp.com) as my subversions client but have been trying to manually clone as tower fails with dependency issues....

Any help is appreciated at this point.

ps for the moving process itself I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3972103) very detailed answer

Comment: The URL you give has to be essentially the one you use to access the SVN repository. Just make sure you get all you need. And such a size repository will take days to slurp down.

Comment: I did that... giving me an error ```no such method url at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/SVN/Ra.pm line 489.``` ...

Comment: Some missing dependency? What _exact_ `git svn` command did you give?

Comment: ```git svn clone --stdlayout --no-metadata -A users.txt file:///dir/to/repsoitory /user/dir/destination``` I think at this point it has something to do with my local svn install so I dumped the repository and am uploading it now to a amazon s3 bucket and will import from there via beanstalkapp.com ... (still uploading) keep you posted. Thanks for the help so far anyway