# How to migrate SVN repo with full codebase to GIT repo?

Tags: git

Can anyone please provide proper urls pdf or detailed steps to migrate SVN/CVS repos to GIT_repo ?

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/how-to-migrate-svn-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can just get each repository and make a new git repository from it by doing:

```
git svn clone <respository url>
```

Then you can push it out to your central git repository.

Rinse and repeat.

Comment: thank you all. i will look into these solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The [Git website](http://git-scm.com/) has a nice looking page on migrating from a Subversion repo to a git one here:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git