# How can I straighten out my Git local repository (I used XCode's Source Control)

Tags: git, version-control, xcode5

I created what I thought was a Git repository named GitRepos.git.  I have been using XCode5 to commit my changes to the local repository.  This is what I see when I select Source Control in XCode 5:

[image]

Originally, this particular project was under Subversion (with 11 .svn files in random folders, which I attribute to XCode's Source Control problems); so I deleted all of the .svn folders and tried to create a new local Git repository.  When I did this, I felt there should have been ONE trunk, not 11 of them.  When I look at the SurveyorLeveling folder in Finder, there is only ONE .git folder (as seen in the image below) as it should be; I haven't a clue where all of the Trunks came from.

[image]

**So my question is:  How do I straighten this mess out?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this answer ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/how-to-migrate-svn-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository)) on how to move properly from svn to git. Git typically has a master, origin, and clones. You will probably need to merge any changes and checkout a new project so that you have a single svn project and then you could try the svn to git script ([link](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git)). Hopefully that will help, if so please accept the answer otherwise provide some feedback.

Comment: Tommie C:  thank you... several of the embedded links inspired me! :D

Thank you.