# How to move commits between repositories?

Tags: git, svn

I have a bunch of commits applied to SVN repository, now I need to move them to git repository. I was thinking of applying the commits one by one using patches, but those patches use relative path that differs in both repositories, e.g. /trunk/project/src/main/java/... in svn and /project/src/main/java/... in git is there a way to create patches that have relative path to  src/main, not trunk/project/src....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git svn doesn't work for me, it fails with some nasty errors: /usr/lib/perl/....
So I figured this issue the following way using IntelliJ IDEA:

1. apply patches one by one
2. in apply patch window I changed the folder hierarchy for each file in the initial commit
3. changed the folder to the git folder.

But this approach is time-consuming

Comment: I would suggest to try solving the *perl* error. Probably could be something easily to solve. And will let you to play with the *Power of Git* ;)

Comment: I've already solved my issue, hope these explanations would help someone else. If I had 1000+ commits I would have digged into those perl errors, in current implementation git svn doesn't seem a reasonable approach to me.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this as a comment but I do not have 50 reputation points, oh well. I believe the answer to your question can be found here:

[How to migrate SVN repository with history to a new Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/migrate-svn-repository-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository)

Answer (score 0):

You should use **[svn clone](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html)**

`git svn clone <SVN_REPOSITORY_URL>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you try [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git)? It's really a powerful tool based on git-svn. I have moved lots of svn repos to git repos using it. You may have a try to see if the perl error is still there.