# svn to git migration: incomplete history

Tags: git, svn, migration

I'm migrating my SVN repository according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3972103) answer.
Everything goes smooth except that in the end I do not have the complete history. I could track the source of the problem down to a "SVN move" which I made.

This is what I did:
At the beginning my SVN repo had no `trunk` `branches` `tags` dirs. Somewhen I introduced them and moved everything into trunk (and then I created a branch, that's the reason I decided to introduce the new folder structure).

So after migrating the SVN repo to git only the history after the introduction of the new folder structure is available.

I reproduced this issue in a very simple scenario.

History in SVN:
[image]

History in git:
[image]

The zip which contains SVN repo / git repo:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ecy54st05qah4up/svn_git_problem.zip?dl=0

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I get a lot of popups and virus errors with the link to the repo zip file. Can you post it on a site like dropbox.com which doesn't have popups and ads?

Comment: done. my apology for the bad link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify `--stdlayout`, `git svn clone` will only pay attention to svn commits that modify files under paths /trunk, /branches or /tags - other commits will be ignored.  You still end-up with a valid clone of your repository, but history from r1 through to the creation of your standard-layout will be lost, as you have observed.  Since you want your Git repository to understand trunk, branches and tags following the layout change, you still want `--stdlayout`, otherwise git clone will combine all branches into a single tree with /trunk /branches /tags, which is not what you want.

What you can do if you really care deeply about the pre-layout-change history (and if this is strictly a one-off migration, no SVN commits after moving to Git), is to run `git svn clone` twice - once with `--stdlayout` and once without.  The stdlayout version will become your eventual repository, and the non-stdlayout version can be used during the migration only, to stitch the pre-layout-change history underneath the new layout, at the point of the reorganisation.  This can be done by cherry-pick-ing all of your post-reorg commits onto a snapshot of the repository at the time of the re-org.

Once you clone both repos, you'll notice that at the point of the copy to the new layout, there's a common tree-hash for trunk.  Here's an example (not using your repo sorry, so hashes differ):

**(in stdlayout repo)**:

```
# git log --pretty=raw
commit 44f2f60e00117dfd51fd7d6431b697ec0ccc863d
tree 5cf62e006bb7b58171010fc0ffaba08ca97520da
parent d403c6ce0789cf584af9abb945bcfd88721e391e
author (no author) <(no author)@4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4> 1420411603 +0000
committer (no author) <(no author)@4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4> 1420411603 +0000

    change 4 after folder structure & branch

    git-svn-id: http://<redacted>/trunk@9 4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4

commit d403c6ce0789cf584af9abb945bcfd88721e391e
tree d6c0d6cf271be5146b26781ab9bd78736d86ace3
parent 0c5873eab204942ffe56370cc6e1d31e5372da13
author (no author) <(no author)@4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4> 1420411513 +0000
committer (no author) <(no author)@4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4> 1420411513 +0000

    changed: moved to new folder structure

    git-svn-id: http://<redacted>/trunk@7 4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4

commit 0c5873eab204942ffe56370cc6e1d31e5372da13
tree 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
author (no author) <(no author)@4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4> 1420411460 +0000
committer (no author) <(no author)@4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4> 1420411460 +0000

    new folder structure

    git-svn-id: http://<redacted>/trunk@6 4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4
```

**(in the full, non-stdlayout repo)**:

```
commit ec52fff6ee1d65eadfa1d18aa4b74b553fc693e1
tree cfda32eb39248fa5969d15a21d2f8014189e88c2
parent 685fe9961abfee4d4913e83cf5a4a7e8d459a1a1
author (no author) <(no author)@4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4> 1420411603 +0000
committer (no author) <(no author)@4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4> 1420411603 +0000

    change 4 after folder structure & branch

    git-svn-id: http://<redacted>@9 4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4

commit 685fe9961abfee4d4913e83cf5a4a7e8d459a1a1
tree 817306fad0ed5466d877437cdda12ff39a0df725
parent 02caf52174c588f1d394815201b764f9abdaa640
author (no author) <(no author)@4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4> 1420411565 +0000
committer (no author) <(no author)@4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4> 1420411565 +0000

    created new branch

    git-svn-id: http://<redacted>@8 4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4

commit 02caf52174c588f1d394815201b764f9abdaa640
tree c041405a580beaef0a4e50923e9279e179c917a8
parent 37d77b8f1168d00b943e0bca3cab277cf89e7e84
author (no author) <(no author)@4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4> 1420411513 +0000
committer (no author) <(no author)@4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4> 1420411513 +0000

    changed: moved to new folder structure

    git-svn-id: http://<redacted>@7 4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4

commit 37d77b8f1168d00b943e0bca3cab277cf89e7e84
tree d6c0d6cf271be5146b26781ab9bd78736d86ace3
parent 3a4784719bd95af5bf59de96310a1d6a38af562e
author (no author) <(no author)@4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4> 1420411460 +0000
committer (no author) <(no author)@4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4> 1420411460 +0000

    new folder structure

    git-svn-id: http://<redacted>@6 4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4

commit 3a4784719bd95af5bf59de96310a1d6a38af562e
tree d6c0d6cf271be5146b26781ab9bd78736d86ace3
parent 2fb41dab5a7389ab32419b8b270d955631aaaefa
author (no author) <(no author)@4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4> 1420411421 +0000
committer (no author) <(no author)@4ed80924-4846-11e4-8279-c5809b3f22e4> 1420411421 +0000

    update 4

... etc., continues.
```

Note that in the stdlayout repo, commit `d403c6c` is tree `d6c0d6c`, and in the full clone, both commits `37d77b8` and its parent `3a47847` also have that same tree.  You might think this odd at first, until you realize that the creation of /trunk /branches /tags in the git-svn clone is actually a no-op, since Git does not track empty directories.

In the stdlayout repo, you can import the full-clone non-standard clone:

```
# git remote add fullclone ../fullclone
# git fetch fullclone
```

Then checkout a new branch from the "new folder structure" commit from the full repo:

```
# git checkout -b fix-history 37d77b8
```

Then replay all commits from this point forward in the standard-layout repo:

```
# git cherry-pick d403c6c..master
```

This might take a while to run if you have many post re-org commits, as each commit is re-committed on the new branch.  The result should be a stitched-together history of trunk pre and post the reorganisation.