# Bonobo Git Server and SVN

Tags: git, bonobo

I've installed Bonobo Git Server (3.4.2.0)  locally. I have a SVN server that contains old repositories?
How can I import these repositories to work under Bonobo Git Server .

Answer (score 3):

I too, was/is in the same boat having to migrate our SVN repositories to git (using Bonobo server).

Pretty much followed the instructions in [Troy Hunts' blog](http://www.troyhunt.com/) post [here](http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/08/migrating-from-subversion-to-git-with.html)

I deviated by creating an authors file to map svn users to git users, thus appending **--authors ../authors.txt** to the **svn2git** command line.

When supplying an authors file, svn2git will stop if there is no record in the file.

The authors file format is 1 line per author
SVNUser = Full Name <email@domain>

Comment: Thanks for the link to that blog: that helped me to move 100+ revisions of a large project to git.

Answer (score 1):

Git can import SVN projects

`git svn clone <repo>`

Taken from:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git

More Resources:

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-overview/

[How to migrate SVN repository with history to a new Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/migrate-svn-repository-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository)

Answer (score 0):

What I did was

1 Create a new repo in Bonobo

2 Clone that to my desktop

3 In the clone,

```
git svn init http://192.168.x.y/svn/my_repo/trunk
git svn fetch
git push origin master
```