# Git-svn creates a detached branch root

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I migrated an svn repository's trunk to git. I then made some commits to the git repo. 
I am now migrating an old svn branch to the new git repo. 
To do this I added `svn-remote.url` and `svn-remote.fetch config` to `.git/config`. When I now do `git svn fetch` and subsequently checkout using `git svn checkout` I get detached tree in SourceTree:

[image: Detached root]

The right most purple branch is as if its without a root, whereas it should branch off just where the other branch is branching from.

Comment: If you examine the first purple commit, does it have a parent? This will distinguish a real orphan from a GUI issue.

Comment: @Useless how do I do that?

Comment: How did you do the initial migration from svn to git?

Comment: @MykolaGurov As described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3972103/269452)

Comment: means you used ` --no-metadata`, after which you should not be surprised git-svn cannot track branches imported afterwards as detached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments it looks like the `--no-metadata` git-svn key was used which erases the data from which it could build proper tree. Don't use that key if you plan to keep svn synced in the future.