# migrate SVN repository (which is hosted on a server) to Git

Tags: git, svn

I have been assigned a task where I have to move the SVN repository which is currently hosted on a server to Git. So far my research I found GitHub can be used for the repository collaboration. But in my case requirement is to set up a own Git Server, I am thinking to set up the Git on the same server where SVN is hosted.
This is how I am thinking to proceed on this :
-first set up the Git server(seeking help in setting up the Git)
--then clone the SVN repository to Git server.
But I am not really sure the way I am thinking is correct or not.
Can somebody please help me in getting the clear picture on how do I need to proceed?

Any help is really appreciated
Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to migrate SVN repository with history to a new Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/how-to-migrate-svn-repository-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository)

Answer (score 0):

Set a different GIT server.

Clone the code from the svn repository to GIT by using the command
$ git svn clone

Comment: how to set up a Git server? using the above command will history too be copied?