# svn to git migration -- Filesystem has no item

Tags: git, perl, svn

I'm trying to move a project on a server (using svn) to another server (using git). My approach is converting svn to git first, then pushing the git repository to the new server.

While I was trying to convert svn to git, I referred to this link --
[How to migrate SVN repository with history to a new Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/how-to-migrate-svn-repository-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository)

It worked fine, until I hit --

```
Filesystem has no item: Working copy path 'branches/Some_Tests' does not exist in repository at /mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm line 312.
```

The path in question definitely exists in the repository, and I have no problem commit changes to the files in the folder. Apparently I don't know much about perl. But if anyone has any suggestion in modifying script or any different approach, I'd definitely love to try it out. Appreciate all the help!

Comment: Which script are you using? Based on the error message it tries to migrate the repository branches from your local working copy which is a bit suspicious. If it is this one: `git svn clone http://svn/repo/here/trunk`, then it can migrate only trunk which means probably you should append trunk to your repository url.

Comment: This is the command line I'm using ... git svn clone --stdlayout --authors-file=users.txt 
svn+ssh://zhenyuh@svn-stg.XXXX.XXXX/var/svnroot/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/ dest_dir-tmp       And, I'm running this command line in svn repository, with branch/trunk/tag mapping. @Lajos Veres

Comment: Is your repository really follows the standard layout? It looks like it can't find that specific branch. Maybe it worth try to skip it. It seems to be a quite complicated tool: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn

Comment: I found this http://jmoses.co/2014/03/21/moving-from-svn-to-git.html, and it worked for me. so, mkdir, cd into it, init with svn repo url, config with user.txt, and fetch. branch/trunk/tag are all in the new dir. I didn't figure out what is exactly going wrong with my first approach, but I think @LajosVeres is right about "only migrating trunk", I think....