# Problems on migrating from svn to git

Tags: git, svn

I'm migrating a number of SVN repositories to GIT. As guideline I'm using this tutorial: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-prepare

Initially, everything was ok using the svn-migration-scripts.jar that they provide. But, in the "clean-git" step, when I got this error:

> Checking for obsolete branches...
>    svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://my-svn-server-path'
>   svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.

Checking the documentation, it looks like there is no "username" parameter (or something like that) for the "clean-git" option. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this Tutorial they use a .jar converter but I would recomment to use directly git & bash which will make you more flexible. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3972103/3524844).

If you get it work you could copy&paste the commands to get a short bash script (if you want to convert a stack of repos automatically)

Comment: Hmmm. I'll try. Thanks!