# What is git checking through while cloning svn repo?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3972103/542270) is a short manual on rewriting SVN repo to git. After executing the this command:

```
git svn clone --stdlayout --no-metadata --authors-file=users.txt svn://hostname/path dest-dir
```

the following messages can be seen in console:

```
This may take a while on large repositories
Checked through r89900
```

What is git checking through exactly? Is it possible to count it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is fetching your data from subversion repository.

"Checked through rXXXXX" - rXXXXX are actual subversion revision numbers.
You can compare the svn logs against git logs.

Also these revision numbers are mapped to Git's sha-1 commits.

```
    git checkout remotes/<Remote Name>
    git svn log --show-commit --oneline

    Output:
    r50 | 77c9acf | "SVN Commit message"
    ...
    r1 | 84e6c49 | "SVN Commit message"
```

You cannot count, but git displays the current revision it is going through. It goes till the Head revision of your SVN repository. Which means from the [example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/celix) you mentioned it should count till the revision you specified, well the current revision for your example is 1768893.