# Git-SVN clone When will this end?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I started following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/how-to-migrate-svn-repository-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository) post to perform a migration from SVN to GIT.
6 days ago, I executed this:

```
git svn fetch
```

And it's still running! I can see the the console log keep changing the revision numbers and I can see the directory keep grow in size. At the moment it's 12GB.

So my SVN repo is big I get that, it also has many branches which not helping. The question is there a way to see what is the current progress in terms of percentage? I simply want to know how many percent of fetching been completed already.

Comment: It can even take few weeks !!!! you have huge repository, I once had a customer who migrated 14GB repo and it took him 3 WEEKS!!! :-(

Comment: @CodeWizard not helping man! Getting depressed will not help me convinced my team that it will end some day. I need some real estimations

Comment: Just being honest :-)

Comment: Well, progress percentage should roughly be the revision you see in the console divided by the max revision in your SVN repo multiplied by 100.

Answer (score 3):

`git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty of tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

The nirvdrum `svn2git` under the hood uses `git-svn`, so it is not the right tool either. Using the KDE `svn2git` I personally needed about 2 hours to convert a repository that needed about 1 week with `git-svn`.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

There are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: If svn2git is so much better that git-svn, wouldn't it make sense to send a pull request to the git-svn with a warning on "init" highlighting the pitfalls if the conversion goes beyond simple one-time without hiccups? To prevent the numerous questions under the `git-svn` tag before the problem strikes?

Comment: It simply is for a totally different use case. git-svn is for using Git as front-end to an existing SVN server to which you want to commit back. If you use a screwdriver to get a nail into a wall, should there be a label on it, saying "don't hit a nail with me"?  It works, but you will not get the best result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the default `git svn` use this tool which perform much better and much faster.

https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git

I have used it as well and its much better.
Here is a post evaluating the process and showing few highlights.

http://blog.smartbear.com/software-quality/migrating-from-subversion-to-git-lessons-learned/

Comment: Tnx I try it, but back to my original question. Do you think I can some how make any assumptions based on the .git size compared to svn repo size?

Comment: No since each svn commit is converted to git commit and its based upon the number of commits, 100K+ commits can take few days and even more.

Comment: Are you sure the nirvdrum `svn2git` is faster? I would really wonder if that's the case. Afair it uses `svn2git` under the hood and makes some additional steps, so it should in fact be even slower than plain `git-svn`, sharing some of its drawbacks.