# git svn fetch has been running for over 3 weeks but does not show revisions in logs

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have been running `git svn fetch` for almost a month now and its does show that it is running because it is indeed generating the logs and continuously, however, I do not see any revision numbers in the logs to find out what is it that it's actually fetching. All the previous conversions I did always showed the current revisions that they were fetching but not this one and it has been running for over 3 weeks now.

Below is a snippet from several thousands line of logs it has generated since:

```
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Library/Boost/boost_1_56_0/tools/regression/xsl_reports/xsl/test/test_re_match.xsl
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Library/Boost/boost_1_56_0/tools/regression/xsl_reports/xsl/v2/add_expected_results.xsl
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Library/Boost/boost_1_56_0/tools/regression/xsl_reports/xsl/v2/boostbook_log.xsl
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Library/Boost/boost_1_56_0/tools/regression/xsl_reports/xsl/v2/common.xsl
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Library/Boost/boost_1_56_0/tools/regression/xsl_reports/xsl/v2/dump_toolsets.xsl
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Library/Boost/boost_1_56_0/tools/regression/xsl_reports/xsl/v2/expected_to_1_33_format.xsl
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Library/Boost/boost_1_56_0/tools/regression/xsl_reports/xsl/v2/html/issues_legend.html
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Library/Boost/boost_1_56_0/tools/regression/xsl_reports/xsl/v2/html/library_developer_legend.html
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Library/Boost/boost_1_56_0/tools/regression/xsl_reports/xsl/v2/html/library_user_legend.html
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Library/Boost/boost_1_56_0/tools/regression/xsl_reports/xsl/v2/html/make_tinyurl.html
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Library/Boost/boost_1_56_0/tools/regression/xsl_reports/xsl/v2/html/master.css
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Library/Boost/boost_1_56_0/tools/regression/xsl_reports/xsl/v2/html/summary_developer_legend.html
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Library/Boost/boost_1_56_0/tools/regression/xsl_reports/xsl/v2/html/summary_user_legend.html
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Library/Boost/boost_1_56_0/tools/regression/xsl_reports/xsl/v2/issues_page.xsl
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Library/Boost/boost_1_56_0/tools/regression/xsl_reports/xsl/v2/links_page.xsl
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Library/Boost/boost_1_56_0/tools/regression/xsl_reports/xsl/v2/produce_expected_results.xsl
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Library/Boost/boost_1_56_0/tools/regression/xsl_reports/xsl/v2/result_page.xsl
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Library/Boost/boost_1_56_0/tools/regression/xsl_reports/xsl/v2/runners.xsl
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Library/Boost/boost_1_56_0/tools/regression/xsl_reports/xsl/v2/summary_page.xsl
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Tools/ELF_To_FW_Image/.cproject
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Tools/ELF_To_FW_Image/.project
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Tools/ELF_To_FW_Image/elf_to_fw_image.cpp
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Tools/LLAC_Serial_Tunnel/Doc/Sequence_Diagram.asta
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Tools/LLAC_Serial_Tunnel/Doc/Sequence_Diagrams.pdf
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Tools/LLAC_Serial_Tunnel/Doc/Serial_over_LLAC-Draft_with_notes.pages
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Tools/LLAC_Serial_Tunnel/Doc/Serial_over_LLAC-Draft_with_notes.pdf
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Tools/LLAC_Serial_Tunnel/Doc/Test_Virtual_Serial_Port/virtual_terminal_application.py
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/Tools/LLAC_Serial_Tunnel/Doc/Test_Virtual_Serial_Port/virtual_terminal_host.py
        D       EP1C/EP1C_0x00010024/
        A       EP1C/0x00010024/Tools/LLAC_Serial_Tunnel/Doc/Sequence_Diagram.asta
```

When I run `ps -ef | grep git`, this is what I get as output:

```
root      8142 20342  0 02:06 ?        00:00:00 git svn fetch
root      8143  8142  0 02:06 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/perl /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn fetch
root      8196  8143  0 02:06 ?        00:00:00 git cat-file --batch
root      8365  8143 99 02:07 ?        00:04:12 git update-index -z --index-info
root      8372  8143  0 02:07 ?        00:00:00 git ls-tree -r --name-only -z 042a8d9e3c80f2bdf354ee35a452e38b38958e4a
root      8588  5750  0 02:11 pts/8    00:00:00 grep git
```

P.S. I have gone through enough answer till now to know that git-svn is not the best of the tool to use for one time migration from SVN to GIT and I should have used some other tool(s) like sv2git as mentioned in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41864351/14933312). So, lets not go to suggestions on that as I don't want to use a new tool and wait for another week or so.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bringing it to the top in case it got lost and did not catch the right eyes.