# How to convert a local checkout of a Subversion repo with local modifications with git-svn?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I checked out some SVN repositories and created a project out of them. After some changes and configuration I found out that I can use git for my SVN repositories. But the only way I found was to clone the repositories with git-svn. Since I already checked out the repositories and worked on them, I'd like to convert the existing repositories. Is it possible? What is the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Local checkouts don't contain enough information (branches, tags, history). To convert SVN repo to git one needs access to SVN server or at least a dump from `svnadmin dump`.

There are many tools and ways to convert SVN to git. See [How to migrate SVN repository with history to a new Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/how-to-migrate-svn-repository-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository)

You create authors files that maps SVN login names to git format `name <email>` and run `git svn clone`.

There are also other tools similar to `git svn`. There are [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git) (and [fast-export](https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git)), [reposurgeon](http://www.catb.org/~esr/reposurgeon/) and other.

Comment: Is it possible to "clone" a SVN repository into an already existing  SVN checkout as git-svn repository? As you said, the local checkout need some additional information from the server and I have access to the server.

Comment: I don't think so. I'm sure `git svn clone` requires an empty directory.