# Moving branches from svn to git

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-svn

I have 2 branches in SVN - trunk and release(branches from trunk).
The intention is to migrate them into a SINGLE repository in GIT.

```
SVN(trunk)----->GIT(master)
SVN(release)---->GIT(release) - where GIT(release) has been branched from GIT(master)
```

Thereafter,we refresh the corresponding SVN source->GIT destination branches daily for a temporary intervening window of migration.

Is this possible?
If so,How to achieve this?

Comment: Did you look at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I migrate an SVN repository with history to a new Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/how-do-i-migrate-an-svn-repository-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository)

Comment: Are you going to accept an answer?

Answer (score 2):

First, make a backup (or two) of your svn repository.

Then, install [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git). On MacOS:

```
brew install ruby
gem install svn2git
```

Or on Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core git-svn ruby
sudo gem install svn2git
```

Then (optionally, but recommended) list all of the authors in the svn repository:

```
svn log --quiet \
| grep -E "r[0-9]+ \| .+ \|" \
| cut -d'|' -f2 \
| sed 's/ //g' \
| sort \
| uniq
```

and create an [authors.txt](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git#authors) file to map svn authors to the accounts you want to use in git.

Run `svn2git`:

```
mkdir new-git-repos
cd new-git-repos
svn2git path-to-svn-repos --no-minimize-url --authors path-to-authors.txt
```

Verify the new git repository (`git log`, `git tag`, `git branch -a`, etc.), rename branches and tags if necessary, and optionally push the new repos to a server.

See the svn2git [README.md](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git#initial-conversion) for more recipes. Use [svnadmin](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnadmin) if you have access to the svn master repository and you need to apply more complicated rewritings of the commit history before conversion to git.