# How to migrate repos from SVN to Gerrit?

Tags: git, svn, migration, gerrit

There is a huge repo in SVN.
Would like to migrate all these repos to Gerrit.

- How are `SVN` and `Gerrit` different?
- What all things to be considered while migrating from SVN to Gerrit?
- What all things to be taken care (like list of files, folders, size etc)?
- Any inter-dependency between repos?

If SVN to Gerrit migration can be done, further repo to be synced between Gerrit to SVN

> Is it just copying files from one location to another location (similar to scp) ?

I am totally new to these. Are there tools available for these ?
How can this be started ? I really need your help here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I migrate an SVN repository with history to a new Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/how-do-i-migrate-an-svn-repository-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository)

Comment: Since Gerrit is Git-based the existing answer should cover most or all aspects of your problem.

Comment: @Filburt Thank you. Let me check that and let you know.

Comment: There is also a nice [blog post](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git) from git itself.