# svn to git migration of a branch with history

Tags: git, svn, gitlab, git-svn

I have a SVN branch which I want to move to git but with all the history of the branch. I tried a lot of permutations and combinations as below but none of them worked. Could someone please help me? I am new to git. I have tried svn to git migration without history and it has worked properly.

```
      svn log -q <SVN_BRANCH_REPO> | awk -F '|' '/^r/ {sub("^ ", "", $2); sub(" $", "", $2); print $2" = "$2" <"$2">"}' | sort -u > users.txt

    git svn clone --stdlayout --no-metadata --authors-file=users.txt <SVN_BRANCH_REPO> tmp
```

the tmp here returns an empty directory. I tried :

```
     git svn clone -r HEAD --no-metadata --authors-file=users.txt <SVN_BRANCH_REPO> tmp1
```

Post this I did the following steps:

```
    cd tmp1
    git svn fetch
    git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:mehtakar/gitexample.git
    git commit --amend --reset-author
    git push -u origin master
```

this also does not commit the history in the master branch. Could someone please let me know what am I missing?

Comment: Did you see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3972103/3535187? Does your SVN-Repo has following layout "trunk/, branches/, tags/"?

Comment: @JkbLskw  yes i did check but didnt help. Yes my repo has trunk branches and tags

Comment: Is there a log for your command "git svn clone"? That would help.

Comment: @JkbLskw : the second git clone command in my question jus creates a new directory and the log for these are simple logs as below:

Comment: Initialized empy git repository in C:\Temp
  A    file
  A    File1
W:  +empty_dir:  com/main/java/filter
W:  +empty_dir:  com/test/resources/conf

r101300= 5ecdfjvbgg837453bt34t73ttb39ugb3 (refs/remotes/git-svn)
Checked out HEAD: SVN_REPO_LINK
Creating empty directory : com/main/java/filter
Creating empty directory:  com/test/resources/conf

Comment: What is the encoding of your users.txt file?

Comment: @JkbLskw  I have not specified it, how do we do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227324/discussion-between-jkblskw-and-karan-mehta).