# How to migrate repository from PVCS Version Manager to GitHub?

Tags: git, github, pvcs

I want to migrate all history and versions of my project repository from PVCS VM to Git/GitHub. I believe that it is possible to do this migration, but i didn't know the way to. Can you anyone share your knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but you can try a [Importer for SVN by Polarion](https://polarion.plm.automation.siemens.com/downloads/svn): it includes one for PVCS to SVN.

Once you have imported your repository to an SVN one, it is easier to convert said Subversion repository to Git, [using SubGit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28364465/6309).

Comment: Hi @Rajkumar, were you able to migrate from pvcs to github successfully ? I cannot find the tool in Polarion now.